# A colleague has committed over my commit - how?

Tags: git

I have the following situation. A few days ago I had a commit which was the latest in the HEAD/MASTER.

I came back to work a couple of days later and my commit wasn't there anymore. It looks like someone removed my commit and did some funky. Having a look at the revision history in tortoise GIT it seems to show this but I need some help with the explanation.

Could someone please have a look at the revision history and tell me how someone might have removed my commit? In the history below I am "Richard Riviere" and I have placed an arrow where it seems to show something committing ober my commit. What is the bracket over a range of commits?

[image]

thanks

Comment: Not familiar with that client, but it looks like a branch and then a merge back into master branch.

Comment: It looks like you had a fast-forward merge update after pulling master.  Navigate to the specific commit that you're interested in and do a `git show <SHA1>`.  It *should* still be there so long as you didn't have major merge conflicts.

Comment: So is the commit you're looking for on the screenshot?

Comment: @Makoto: if it was FF - there wouldn't be a merge. By definition.

Comment: As @ChristopherMarshall says. The commit currently marked as `master` (Merge branch 'master'...) should include both your changes (Trading hour updates) and cramadhe's (pingable code stuff). Your code did not disappear (since you were the one that is shown as responsible for the merge), your commit did not disappear, they are both in the current `master`'s history.

Comment: I was responsible for the merge? Was that because I did a pull and not a fetch?

Comment: Yes; pull = fetch + merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cramadhe pushed a branch on `origin/master`, a branch started from just *before* your commit.

You just pulled from `origin/master`, merging it with your own local `master` branch: this wasn't a fast-forward merge, but a classic merge between two branches.

It is possible that your changes have been impacted by what has just been merged locally.

If you just did merge, you can review the differences between your file before and after the merge, [using `ORIG_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/967611/6309):

```
git diff ORIG_HEAD HEAD -- yourfile
```

Comment: I did a pull which I believe does a merge. So how did that branch get created on top of the origin/master. I thought origin/master was a branch in itself? It's dangerous because that person has overwritten my changes

Comment: @Richie what you see is the result of the merge between `master` and `origin/master`, resulting in a new commit (on `master`) with two parents (one your previous `master` commit, the other being `origin/master`). That happens when you do some local work while others are pushing to the remote: when you are pulling, you are merging those `origin/master` commits pushed in the meantime. That can result in local work being affected (but never lost: it is after all a version control system: you can diff and restore files). Pushing more often can mitigate that risk.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very good explanation. I think in the future I won't do a pull. I think it should be a fetch.