# show fetched commits after git pull --rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-diff, pull, diffstat

Is there a way to see what commits have been pulled in from the remote repository after you do a `git pull --rebase`?

In other words: `git pull` will show a summary of changed files at the end (like `git diff --stat`). `Git pull --rebase` does not. How can I see this information anyway, if at all possible?

I know this is possible after a normal `git pull` or by doing a manual `git fetch` first, by comparing local & remote branches using `git log master..origin/master --stat` or similar, but this does not work after a `git pull --rebase`, unless I'm doing something wrong...

To clarify, my question is 2-part:
1) How to view diffstat (summary of changed files) after a `git pull --rebase`, similar to what `git pull` shows.
2) How to view log of all new "incoming" commits after a `git pull --rebase`.

Comment: If you're rebasing `master` to `origin/master`, the range `master..origin/master` will be empty; so it's normal that `git log master..origin/master --stat` doesn't output anything. Besides, doesn't `git diff --stat master@{1}` (after `git pull --rebase`) do the trick?

Comment: I had to add quotes around "develop@{1}" or it would strip the braces and fail, but yes, that shows the same output as a ´git pull` or ´git pull --rebase --stat` (see torek's answer)! I have no idea what "@{1}" means however....

Comment: `develop@{1}` means "where `develop` pointed to before it last moved"; see the bottom of [this answer by VonC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git/964927#964927). If torek's answer completely solves your problem, consider accepting it.

Comment: I have deleted my answer, since any git log X..Y --stat isn't working.

Comment: @VonC, well actually, with your answer, combined with Jubobs' answer introducing me to the @{1} notation, I may have found a solution to part 2 of my question.
Indeed your `git log HEAD..ORIG_HEAD` or the other way around doesn't do what I want, but `git log "origin/develop@{1}"..origin/develop` does! Outputs only the new commits coming from origin :-)

Comment: Great! Do you want me to restore the answer, for the @{1} part?

Comment: Up to you. I don't know if I can "accept" 2 answers though... Pretty new here...

Comment: I have restored and amended the answer, but keep torek's answer selected: I find it easier to use, and quite accurate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, `git rebase` has had this all along (well, since 1.6.something).  Remember that `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` or `git rebase` (as directed by various options and settings).  That is, `git pull` does a pair of underlying git operations.

The reason it does not work after you have finished your `git pull` is that `git pull` is in fact that pair of operations, and if you just did one pair, there are probably no new changes brought in by your *second* `git fetch`, so there is nothing new to show.  If you were to use your reflog history to reset items to the state they were in before the *first* pair of operations, the second pair of operations would have something to show.

You can (as I see [VonC has already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623456/1256452)) get an after-the-fact report on what changed in either the upstream or your local branch using your own reflogs.  But presumably you want to see this on the *next* `git pull` even if that does a `rebase`, and that's where a sneaky set of git defaults come in.

If you manually add `--stat` to your `git pull` line, the `pull` script passes this option on to either `git merge` or `git rebase` (whichever one it runs).  If you *leave this option out*, git relies on a default option.

The default `--stat` option for `git merge` is the setting in your configuration's `merge.stat`, **which defaults to True**.  The default `--stat` option for `git rebase` is the setting in your configuration's `rebase.stat`, **which defaults to False**.

Let me repeat that, because it's just peculiar and non-obvious (I only discovered this because of your question—I generally avoid `git pull` myself).

**The default `--stat` option for `merge` is `True` but the default `--stat` option for `rebase` is `False`.**

If you set the defaults yourself, you can make the stat output show up.

Alternatively, you can pass an explicit `--stat` to `git pull`.

Note that you can also set `pull.rebase` (to either `True`, meaning default to rebasing, or `preserve`, meaning default to rebase with `--preserve` as well), or `branch.name.rebase` (to `True` or `preserve`), to make `git pull` use `--rebase`.  This is independent of whether you supply `--stat` as a `pull` argument.

---

**Edit**: VonC's answer is gone (at least right now) but there are bits of it in various comments.  The trick to use after the fact is that when `git fetch` updates `origin/develop`, *your own* reflog now contains an `origin/develop@{1}`: your own previous value for `origin/develop`, before `git fetch` updated it.  Thus, you can select the revision-set that came in with `origin/develop@{1}..origin/develop`.  Diffing those two with `--stat` will get you the desired output.  Note that you may, or may not depending on your particular shell, have to quote the curly braces in the `@{1}` part.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `rebase.stat` config. +1

Comment: @VonC: neither was I—at first I thought one would have to obtain the diffstat manually, but I checked the documentation for `git rebase` and there was `--stat`, and I checked the `pull` script and it defaulted to *not* passing `--stat` but would pass it if you asked, and then I thought: wait, merge shows stats by default, and rebase doesn't, is that configurable?  And it was!

Comment: @torek. At first I thought you were getting a bit sidetracked. I never said I was doing a git pull _and then_ a git fetch to see what changed ;) But actually, the `git pull --stat` or `rebase.stat` are exactly what I was looking for. Nice find!

Comment: or maybe I did say that... sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try (after the `git pull --rebase`) accessing [the reflog](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery):
(see [`git rev-parse` SPECIFYING REVISIONS](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions))

```
@\{<n>\}, e.g. @{1}
```

> You can use the `@` construct with an empty ref part to get at a **reflog entry** of the current branch.
>   For example, if you are on branch `blabla` then `@{1}` means the same as `blabla@{1}`.

Here `origin/master@{1}` would reference `origin/master` *before* the `fetch` (since `pull` = `fetch` + `merge/rebase`)

To see the fetched commits, the [OP Q-BiC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2875891/q-bic) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622974/show-fetched-commits-after-git-pull-rebase#comment40074118_25622974):

```
git log "origin/develop@{1}"..origin/develop
```

That being said, [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623641/6309) is easier, as it will take care of that step for you, with `--stat` being passed automatically to `git fetch`.

Comment: Is `@{<n>}` synonymous to `HEAD@{<n>}`?

Comment: @Jubobs yes, since git 1.8.5+ (http://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309): `HEAD` = `@`

Comment: Thanks for that. That will save me a few keystrokes in the future.

Comment: This does not have the desired behavior. It also shows your own commits, not just the new "incoming" ones.