# why post-merge git hook not running?

Tags: git, github, merge, githooks

I just wanted to run a git hook(post-merge) to verify what are all the changes happened in the recent pull.

this is my post-merge script

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

echo "======> following are changes made to local repo <======"

git fetch && git log ..origin/master --pretty=format:"%s - %ar by %an (%h)"

echo "=======> ****************** <========"
```

I have given necessary file permission `chmod +x post-merge`

command `git fetch && git log ..origin/master --pretty=format:"%s - %ar by %an (%h)"` runs perfectly when i ran it manually.

But when i do a `git pull origin master` it is showing only

```
echo "======> following are changes made to local repo <======"
echo "=======> ****************** <========"
```

Because `git pull` performs both `git fetch` and `git merge` i tried with

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

    echo "======> following are changes made to local repo <======"

    git log ..origin/master --pretty=format:"%s - %ar by %an (%h)"

    echo "=======> ****************** <========"
```

Where i am going wrong?

git version 1.9.1

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that because `post-merge` is executed **after** `git pull`, that is when `post-merge` is executed, you HEAD is the same with `origin/master`, so you got empty output.

try this:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

echo "======> following are changes made to local repo <======"

git fetch && git log ORIG_HEAD..origin/master --pretty=format:"%s - %ar by %an (%h)"

echo "=======> ****************** <========"
```

the key is `ORIG_HEAD`, which is the last value of HEAD before dangerous operation (includes merge)

for more infomation about `ORIG_HEAD` read [HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)

Comment: i am new to this concept can you explain it little bit?

Comment: `that because post-merge is executed after git pull, that is when post-merge is executed` 

i wanted to check what are all changed after pull.
this means after merge only i need to do this right?
because git pull will do both git fetch and git merge right?

Comment: @h.APP.y `git pull will do both git fetch and git merge` --> yes.

Comment: so how should i over come that?

Comment: @h.APP.y check my latest answer

Comment: if i want to store the changed file names in a variable and want to send through mail server 
`changed_files = \`git fetch && git log ORIG_HEAD..origin/master --pretty=format:"%s - %ar by %an %h"\`` 
and sending through `mailx` 

`echo "demo code alert" | mailx -s "commits pulled to server" abcd@example.com`


but it is returning me changed file not found error how to assign values to a shell variable?

Comment: @h.APP.y `changed_files=$(git fetch && git log ORIG_HEAD..origin/master --pretty=format:"%s - %ar by %an %h")` there is no space around `=`