# How can I quickly check the value of ORIG_HEAD?

Tags: git

I would just like to echo the value of ORIG_HEAD at the command line -- how can I do this? To no avail I tried:

```
$ echo $ORIG_HEAD
```

and

```
$ git echo $ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "the value"?  You can get the raw SHA-1 with `git rev-parse ORIG_HEAD`, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can see what commit `ORIG_HEAD` points to by using the `log` command of git:

```
git log -1 ORIG_HEAD
```

---

What you tried, `$ORIG_HEAD` is parsed by your shell, treating it as a variable that was probably not set so effectively running

```
echo
git echo
```

Where `git echo` is an invalid git command.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for the SHA-1 to be able to pipe to something other command, as @torek mentioned you could do...

```
git rev-parse ORIG_HEAD
```

This comes from the `.git/ORIG_HEAD` file. So you could also do this...

```
cat .git/ORIG_HEAD
```

It is of course worth mentioning that `ORIG_HEAD` and `HEAD` are not the same. [More about that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git) So if you came here looking for how to get the SHA-1 of the `HEAD` use this instead...

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: Simplicity shines. Awesome info.