# GIT POST-MERGE Hook, Get updated files

Tags: git, deployment, githooks, autodeploy

I've a branch titled `uat` on git.

I want to get a clone of all the files which are updated in `merge` in the `uat` branch.
*(Basically idea behind it is to create a build to upload on uat server)*.

I've tried doing this.

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e "s/^refs\/heads\///");
if [ "uat" == "$branch" ]; then
    // to do
    // 1. get all updated files
    // 2. create a clone of these files
fi
```

Can someone please help me with `setp 1` i.e. get all the file updated in current merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the merge just took place (which should be the case in a post-merge hook), you could use [`ORIG_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/964876/6309):

```
git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For a complete solution. Here is how to create a build with `git` `post-merge` `hook`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# get current branch    
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e "s/^refs\/heads\///");

# check if branch name is `uat` (or whatever you prefer)
if [ "uat" == "$branch" ]; then

    # create a folder outside the git repo
    # you can skip this step, if you want a static location
    mkdir -p $(pwd)/../uat/$(basename $(git root));

    # getting updated files, and
    # copy (and overwrite forcefully) in exact directory structure as in git repo
    yes | cp --parents -rf $(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD) $(pwd)/../uat/$(basename $(git root))/;
fi
```

Comment: Nice feedback, in addition to my answer. +1

Comment: @VonC.. Your answer is core of this logic. Thanks!!