# How to use the "colon slash" revision short form and still refer to a commit's parent?

Tags: git

Assume I want to refer to a *the parent of youngest commit whose commit message contains 'foo'.*

`HEAD^{/foo}^` will do the job.
This can be slightly shortened to `@^{/foo}^` (I think).

The `<rev>^{/<text>}` construction has a simplified form, though: `:/<text>`.

Is there any way to use the short form and still refer to the parent of the resulting commit?

Comment: Not directly in a single command. i assume you found the minimal way of doing it. with several commands you can use the git log + grep

Comment: He did not, did he? `<rev>^{/<text>}` is different from `:/<text>`, as the first works only on `<rev>`, the second on all revs. Or did I miss something? I'd also like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the [`git rev-parse` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse), you can combine two of those in order to get the parent of a commit whose message match the regexp.

In a git bash, type:

```
git rev-parse $(git rev-parse :/<text>)^
```

Those are **two commands**:

- first getting the commit with the right message: `git rev-parse :/<text>`
- then getting its parent `git rev-parse $(...)^`

The `$()` will execute the first command `git rev-parse` and give its result to the second command `git rev-parse`.

That will get you the parent of the commit with a commit message matching `<text>`.

---

This differ from using only one command with:

```
git rev-parse HEAD^{/<text>}^
```

Or in Windows CMD:

```
git rev-parse "@^{/<text>}^"
# or, more complex, as ^ is the windows escape sign:
git rev-parse ^@^^{/<text>}^^
```

Comment: `@` would just be an alias for `HEAD` which are both not the topic of the question as it would only search in `HEAD`, not in all refs. Is there no way to get this in just one rev-parse syntax? There might be places outside Bash where such a syntax would be handy.

Comment: @BjörnKautler I agree, but I did not find a way to get the same result with *one* rev-parse syntax.

Comment: Me neither. Maybe this is scope for a feature request or patch to Git. :-) Maybe something like `:{/<text>}^`. If there is really no other way to specify it already.

Comment: @BjörnKautler good idea. Note: I did know about `@` being an alias for `HEAD` (I reported it first in July 2013 for git 1.8.4: http://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309). I just mentioned `@` was not working well when used directly with the `^{/<text>}` notation.

Comment: Works fine for me here

Comment: @BjörnKautler Are you using git on Windows or directly in a Linux environment?

Comment: I'm using it on linux, in cygwin and I even tried with Git for Windows from cmd.exe. The only caveat in the last case was, that you have to enclose the argument in double-quotes, or the cmd.exe will not handle the `@`, `^`, `{` and `}` correctly, meaning not handle it but give it to git.

Comment: @BjörnKautler double-quotes! Of course. I have edited the answer to reflect that syntax, or even another alternative one. But regarding the original question, when using `^{/<text>}`, you would still need two commands instead of one.

Comment: How would these two commands look like? With `^{/<text>}` you cannot get the youngest matching commit of all refs like you do with `:/<text>` or the proposed `:{/<text>}^`. With `^{/<text>}` you just get an error as you must not leave out the ref to be searched in front of it

Comment: @BjörnKautler I have edited the answer to make those two commands more visible.

Comment: I will accept this answer until/unless someone posts a solution which uses rev-parse syntax directly (avoiding the subprocess call), possibly after git is patched to allow this.

Comment: @VonC I still don't get what you meant in the comment "But regarding the original question, when using `^{/<text>}`, you would still need two commands instead of one.". I don't see how you get that effect with `^{/<text>}` at all.

Comment: @BjörnKautler sorry, I got mixed up: I meant with `:/<text>`, you would need two commands.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. Yeah, it seems there is no direct way to express this as long as my proposal or similar does not make it into Git.