# Safe git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

Quite often, when working on one thing, I find some ugliness in unrelated code, fix it and commit separately. Usually, there are multiple such commits, as I find similar problems later.

Finally, I rebase (reorder and squash) so that the commits make more sense. Sometimes, I get merge conflicts and sometimes the resulting working tree differs from the one before rebasing.

- Can such a difference occur even when there were no conflicts?
- Is there a way to get a (huge blinking) warning when the difference occurs?

Comment: I don't know about "huge blinking warning" (!), but can't you just diff the result against the original HEAD commit?  (It sounds like you're already doing that.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, I'm doing it.... but I'm also forgetting. A lot. And this makes the operation unsafe.

Answer (score 3):

> Can such a difference occur even when there were no conflicts?

Maybe not, but human error is a factor we should always consider.

> Is there a way to get a (huge blinking) warning when the difference occurs?

This should do:

```
git diff ORIG_HEAD HEAD
```

To do it automatically, use the `post-rewrite` hook (see [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)):

> #### post-rewrite
>
> This hook is invoked by commands that rewrite commits (git commit --amend, git-rebase; currently git-filter-branch does not call it!). Its first argument denotes the command it was invoked by: currently one of amend or rebase. Further command-dependent arguments may be passed in the future.

Then in the hook script `.git/hooks/post-rewrite` we can compare `ORIG_HEAD` and `HEAD`, and emit a warning if different:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

diff_rebase() {
    # echo "Old HEAD: $(git rev-parse ORIG_HEAD)"
    # echo "New HEAD: $(git rev-parse HEAD)"
    if ! git diff --quiet ORIG_HEAD HEAD; then
        >&2 echo "NOTE: diff detected after rebase!"
    else
        echo "rebase well done"
    fi
}

# bypass git amend
[ "$1" = "rebase" ] && diff_rebase
```

To make the hook available globally, consider config `core.hooksPath`, e.g.:

```sh
git config --global core.hooksPath /usr/local/git-hooks/
```

Then save the script as `/usr/local/git-hooks/post-rewrite`, with executable permission set.

**NOTE**: unfortunately it seems there's a bug that interactive rebase, namely `git rebase -i`, doesn't trigger the hook, when a custom hooks dir is used. (I'm using git 2.9.2)

Comment: Related [`HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/964876/537554)

Comment: it works fine with `git rebase -i` when placed inside `$GIT_DIR/hooks`, namely the default hooks directory.