# optional githook behaving as non-optional

Tags: node.js, git, shell, githooks, post-checkout-hook

I am attempting to make use of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/7996717) in my workflow as `post-merge` and `post-checkout` git hooks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# MIT © Sindre Sorhus - sindresorhus.com

# git hook to run a command after `git pull` if a specified file was changed
# Run `chmod +x post-merge` to make it executable then put it into `.git/hooks/`.

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

check_run() {
    echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}

# Example usage
# In this example it's used to run `npm install` if package.json changed
check_run package.json "npm install"
```

This claims to only run npm install if the `package.json` file is changed.

However on all the machines I have tried this on. The npm install command runs regardless of whether package.json has been changed or not.

To test this I have been creating a new branch at my current commit and then checking it out, thus triggering the `post-checkout` git hook. I would not expect `npm install` to run because the `package.json` is unchanged.

Visual Proof (note the npm warning text):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use a different post-checkout hook, that uses `$1` instead of `ORIG_HEAD`.  (Or, check the number of arguments to decide whether you are being invoked as the post-checkout or post-merge hook, to get the same effect.  Or, if you know that reflogs are always enabled, use `HEAD@{1}` to get the previous value of `HEAD`.)

#### Discussion

Using `ORIG_HEAD` in a post-merge hook makes sense, because `git merge` sets `ORIG_HEAD` to the commit that was current before the merge.  (If the merge was a true merge, rather than a fast-forward, the commit identified by `MERGE_HEAD` and the commit identified by `HEAD^1` are necessarily identical.  If the merge was a fast-forward, however, only `MERGE_HEAD` and the reflog will be able to locate the previous commit hash that was stored in `HEAD` before the merge.)

Using `ORIG_HEAD` in a *post-checkout* hook, however, is blatantly wrong, because `git checkout` *does not* set `ORIG_HEAD`.  This means that if `ORIG_HEAD` even exists at all, it effectively points to some random commit.  (Of course, it actually resolves to whatever commit was left in it by whatever command last updated it: `git merge`, `git rebase`, or any other command that writes to `ORIG_HEAD`.  But the point here is that it does not have any relationship to the commit that was current before the checkout.)  [A post-checkout hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html):

> is given three parameters: the ref of the
>   previous HEAD, the ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have
>   changed), and a flag indicating whether the checkout was a branch
>   checkout (changing branches, flag=1) or a file checkout (retrieving a
>   file from the index, flag=0). This hook cannot affect the outcome of
>   *git checkout*.

(That last sentence is not quite right.  Although the post-checkout hook cannot stop checkout from having updated the index and work-tree, it *can* overwrite various work-tree or index contents, and if it produces a failure exit status, it causes `git checkout` itself to also produce a failure exit status.)

What this all means is that you need to take a different action in a post-checkout hook: use `$1`, the first parameter, to get the hash ID of the previous `HEAD`.  Note that in exotic cases,<sup>1</sup> the post-checkout hook is run on the initial `git clone`, so `$1` can be the  null-ref.  (I'm now curious as to what it is when you use `git checkout --orphan` and then don't create the new branch, as well.  It seems likely that `$1` will be the null-ref here too.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The only way to get a post-checkout hook to run on `git clone` is to have `git clone` install the post-checkout hook.  This is normally impossible, but can be done by pointing your Git to your own template directories that have actual hooks instead of just sample hooks.

Comment: somewhat unrelated question about the code. I've now added another line below what you see above that reads `check_run .gitmodules "git submodule udpate"` but for some reason if package.json is unchanged, it never gets around to the new line. Any ideas?

Comment: That seems odd. To debug the script, `set -x` (or add `-x` to the flags on the `#!` line—might not be possible here, depends on kernel and #! interpretation) and you can watch it run each command. I will note here that `udpate` has a typo (swapped d and p), but of course that's probably just in your comment here, rather than in the script itself.

Comment: I wrote it up as a new question including the output method you suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878982/git-hook-fails-silently

Answer (score 2):

`ORIG_HEAD` should be replaced with `HEAD@{1}` as noted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git) `ORIG_HEAD` is an older, less reliable way to supposedly get the previous state of HEAD. In my case it was not being set.

Comment: Using `HEAD@(1)` will only work if reflogs are enabled. (They probably are, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Torek mentions:

> > ```
> > This hook cannot affect the outcome of git checkout.
> > ```
>
> That last sentence is not quite right.
>
> Although the post-checkout hook cannot stop checkout from having updated the index and work-tree, it can overwrite various work-tree or index contents, and if it produces a failure exit status, it causes git checkout itself to also produce a failure exit status.

That is now (Q4 2020, 3 years later) officially documented with With Git 2.29:

See [commit 3100fd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3100fd55888ce742056cc998343c5fc9f89b2c55) (27 Aug 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2f1757e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f1757e60af788904fcaa37d6d410f834fa3055f), 03 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3100fd55888ce742056cc998343c5fc9f89b2c55): clarify how exit status of `post-checkout` hook is used

> Because the hook runs after the main checkout operation finishes, it cannot affect what branch will be the current branch, what paths are updated in the working tree, etc., which was described as "cannot affect the outcome of 'checkout'".
>
> However, the `exit` status of the hook is used as the `exit` status of the '`checkout`' command and is observable by anybody who spawned the '`checkout`', which was missing from the documentation.
> Fix this.

`githooks` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3100fd55888ce742056cc998343c5fc9f89b2c55/Documentation/githooks.txt#L196-L198):

> This hook cannot affect the outcome of `git switch` or `git checkout`,
> **other than that the hook's exit status becomes the exit status of these two commands**.