# Git Hook Fails Silently

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks, post-checkout-hook

I have a post-checkout and post-merge githook with these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
# MIT © Sindre Sorhus - sindresorhus.com
set -eux  

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id HEAD@{1} HEAD)"

check_run() {
    echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}

echo ''
echo 'running git submodule update --init --recursive if .gitmodules has changed'
check_run .gitmodules "git submodule update --init --recursive"

echo ''
echo 'running npm install if package.json has changed'
check_run package.json "npm prune && npm install"

echo ''
echo 'running npm build:localhost'
npm run build:localhost
```

Strangely if there are no changes to .gitmodules, the script ends rather than progress to check the package.json. (it doesn't even execute the echo lines after line 12)

removing the check_run invocations and putting just the straight commands instead seems to work fine.

removing `check_run .gitmodules "git submodule update --init --recursive"` does work as well. However the same behavior is exhibited in the next line: `check_run package.json "npm prune && npm install"` if package.json has not been changed

Is there something that I am missing that causes check_run to end the script on the first file change not being found?

Visual Proof:
[image]

Comment: maybe specify the full path to the `npm` binary ?

Comment: @t0mm13b if you look at the picture you can see that it never even gets to the line with npm but rather fails during/after grep. That is why I included the echo lines

Comment: even with grep, include a full path to any binary as well,  why not echo the error code `$?` of the last executed command.

Comment: @t0mm13b I didnt know you could do that. but having tested it. grep does return a `1` as its exit code

Comment: the `eval` with $2 as parameter looks suspect, what is the value of $2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `set -e` is the problem here: `-e` means "exit if something fails", where "fails" is defined as "exits nonzero".

We see in the output, as the last few lines:

```
+ check_run .gitmodules 'git submodule update --init --recursive'
+ echo ''
+ grep --quiet .gitmodules
```

(and then nothing else).  The script exited after `grep --quiet`.

Here's the actual definition of `check_run`:

```
check_run() {
    echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}
```

This parses as `left && right` where *left* is the `echo ... | grep ...` and *right* is the `eval "$2"`.

We see that the left part ran and the right part didn't.  Here's where we need to know something about shells: even with `-e` set, they don't *immediately* exit if something fails, *as long as that something is part of a test*.<sup>1</sup>  So this isn't immediately the problem.

But it is still the problem, because `left && right` has, as its exit status, the exit status of the last thing it runs.  The last thing it ran is the *left* pipeline, which was `echo ... | grep ...`.  The exit status of the pipeline is the exit status of its last component,<sup>2</sup> i.e., `grep`.  The grep exits zero if it finds the string (and with `--quiet`, suppresses its output as well), 1 if not, and 2 on generic errors, so the exit status was 1.

Therefore, the exit status of `left && right` was also 1.

Therefore, since `-e` was in effect, the shell exited!

The cure is either to avoid `-e` (but this means if something else fails unexpectedly, the shell plows on, so this might be a bit dangerous), or to make sure that the `left && right` does not make the shell exit.

There is one straightforward way to do the latter: replace `left && right` with `if left; then right; fi`:

```
if echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1"; then
    eval "$2"
fi
```

Note that if `eval "$2"` fails, the shell will still exit.

There is a different and slightly tricky way to do this with a different effect: replace `left && right` with `left && right || true`.  The "and" expression binds more tightly, so this means:

- Evaluate *left*
- If that succeeds (exits zero), evaluate *right*
- If the `&&` fails (either *left* exits nonzero, or *right* is run and *right* exits nonzero), evaluate the `|| true` part, which exits 0.

Hence:

```
echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2" || true
```

always exits 0, `eval`-ing `"$2"` if and only if the left side fails (does not find the grepped-for expression).

If you want `check_run` to plow on even if `eval "$2"` fails, use the second (`|| true`) version.  If you want `check_run` to stop (and have the whole shell exit) under `-e` if `eval "$2"` fails, use the first (`if ...; then`) version.

---

<sup>1</sup>Truly ancient 4BSD `/bin/sh`, long before it went open source, had a bug: `-e` *would* make the shell exit in these cases.  (I think I fixed that one myself at one point, but when 4BSD went to a new sh, not based on Steve Bourne's original code, the bug just wasn't there at all.)

<sup>2</sup>In bash, you can control this in more detail.  In particular you can get the status of *every* component of a pipeline in the `$PIPESTATUS` array variable.