# How to unstage large number of files without deleting the content

Tags: git, version-control

I accidentally added a lot of temporary files using `git add -A`

I managed to unstage the files using the following commands and managed to remove the dirty index.

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm -f
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

The above commands are listed in the `git help rm`. But sadly, my files were also deleted on execution, even though I had given cache option. How can I clear the index without losing the content?

Also it would be helpful if someone can explain the way this pipe operation works.

Comment: `rm -f` is not a git command and doesn't have a `--cached` option. Your local files were deleted before you executed `git rm` so I don't think you can legitimately blame `git rm` for anything.

Comment: @sarat, please consider changing the correct answer to the highly upvoted answer from **Ian Maddox**, as the `git reset --hard` is **not the correct answer** and will in fact delete the content. This will confuse users - as it did me.

Comment: @sarat as Marco says, go on. This page gets a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 1246, accepted):

#### `git reset`

If all you want is to undo an overzealous "git add" run:

```
git reset
```

Your changes will be unstaged and ready for you to re-add as you please.

---

**DO NOT RUN `git reset --hard`.**

It will not only unstage your added files, but will revert any changes you made in your working directory. If you created any new files in working directory, it **will not** delete them though.

Comment: I often find I have to perform `git checkout -- *` as well

Comment: Fun (and useful) fact: `git stash` can save your most recent changes, even when you `git reset --hard` incorrectly

Answer (score 39):

If you have a pristine repo (or HEAD isn't set)**<sup>*[1]*</sup>** you could simply

```
rm .git/index
```

Of course, this will require you to re-add the files that you *did* want to be added.

---

**<sup>*[1]*</sup>** Note (as explained in the comments) this would usually only happen when the repo is brand-new ("pristine") or if no commits have been made. More technically, whenever there is no checkout or work-tree.

Just making it more clear :)

Comment: Yea it's more like deleting the created index itself. Good thing is that, I don't require to re-initialize git. Thanks!

Comment: Are sure it's a safe operation? I just did this (actually moved index out of way) and got all other files staged for deletion.

Comment: @inger "If you have a pristine repo". You clearly didn't have that.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering what you meant by "pristine repo" (I don't feel lucky with google either).. So you meant an empty repo actually?

Comment: @inger Pristine would be the case where you didn't commit anything yet, this is common: doing the initial `git add .` tends to surprise me at the very amount of files I _didn't_ want to add :) In this, very specific, case, I would indeed just nuke the index.

Comment: Ah, so you did mean an empty repo. Quite a specific case indeed:) the question doesn't suggest this scenario, can't see how this became the selected answer for @sarat's case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @inger Agree. I had to assume that the OP had happened to have this exact situation - he doesn't specify it, but his description leaves the possibility. Anyways, I'm just sharing information, and can't influence the voting :(. Have added a word of warning to the answer text, in case it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 22):

#### 2019 update

As pointed out by others in related questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003889/9210961), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60928923/9210961), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61725470/9210961), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044987/9210961), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919257/9210961), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58610415/9210961), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58830990/9210961)), you can now unstage  a file with `git restore --staged <file>`.

To unstage all the files in your project, run the following from the root of the repository (the command is recursive):

```sh
git restore --staged .
```

If you only want to unstage the files in a directory, navigate to it before running the above or run:

```sh
git restore --staged <directory-path>
```

#### Notes

- `git restore` was introduced in [July 2019](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f496b064fc1135e0dded7f93d85d72eb0b302c22) and released in version 2.23.
  With the `--staged` flag, it restores the content of the working tree from HEAD (so it does the opposite of `git add` and does not delete any change).
- This is a new command, but the behaviour of the old commands remains unchanged. So the older answers with `git reset` or `git reset HEAD` are still perfectly valid.
- When running `git status` with staged uncommitted file(s), this is now what Git suggests to use to unstage file(s) (instead of `git reset HEAD <file>` as it used to prior to v2.23).

Answer (score 19):

Use `git reset HEAD` to reset the index without removing files. (If you only want to reset a particular file in the index, you can use `git reset HEAD -- /path/to/file` to do so.)

The pipe operator, in a shell, takes the `stdout` of the process on the left and passes it as `stdin` to the process on the right. It's *essentially* the equivalent of:

```
$ proc1 > proc1.out
$ proc2 < proc1.out
$ rm proc1.out
```

but instead it's `$ proc1 | proc2`, the second process can start getting data before the first is done outputting it, and there's no actual file involved.

Comment: but to how to use it with multiple files. I never have commited these files before.

Comment: Just type `git reset HEAD` without specifying anything else, and it will reset the entire index. You can then just re-add only the files you want.

Comment: I got the following error. I never committed these items before.

`$ git reset HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions`

Comment: Try just `git reset` then, without the `HEAD`.

Comment: I already tried that I ended up in the following error. `$ git reset
fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.`

Answer (score 12):

```
git stash && git stash pop
```

Comment: I would do 'git stash && git stash pop' so that the stash also gets deleted. 'apply' would leave the stash in the stash list.

Answer (score 8):

If HEAD isn't set (i.e., you have no commits yet, but you don't want to just blow away `.git` because you've already set up other repo config you want to keep), you can also do

```
git rm -rf --cached .
```

to unstage everything. This is effectively the same as sehe's solution, but avoids mucking with Git internals.

Comment: this actually tells Git to delete everything in the cached area.

Comment: The cache is also known as the staging area, so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: From sehe, rm .git/index is very dangerous - be sure to read the NOTE he has about a brand new repo! This is much safer for the other 99.999% of the time. I didn't read carefully and had to blow away my working copy and re-clone after doing rm .git/index on my working copy.

Comment: DO NOT use this command! It will change ALL project to the untracked state (including ones that were not staged). This is not a solution to the original question. The correct solution using the 'git rm' command is to ONLY specify the files you want unstaged: git rm -rf --cached <files you want to unstage>.

Comment: You should only use this command when you have a new repo **with no commits yet** (this is what "HEAD isn't set" means), but you don't want to just blow away `.git` because you've set up other repo config you want to keep. I've edited to clarify this.

Answer (score 6):

**Warning: do not use the following command unless you want to lose uncommitted work!**

Using `git reset` has been explained, but you asked for an explanation of the piped commands as well, so here goes:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm -f
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

The command `git ls-files` lists all files git knows about. The option `-z` imposes a specific format on them, the format expected by `xargs -0`, which then invokes `rm -f` on them, which means to remove them without checking for your approval.

In other words, "list all files git knows about and remove your local copy".

Then we get to `git diff`, which shows changes between different versions of items git knows about. Those can be changes between different trees, differences between local copies and remote copies, and so on.
As used here, it shows the unstaged changes; the files you have changed but haven't committed yet. The option `--name-only` means you want the (full) file names only and `--diff-filter=D` means you're interested in deleted files only. *(Hey, didn't we just delete a bunch of stuff?)*
This then gets piped into the `xargs -0` we saw before, which invokes `git rm --cached` on them, meaning that they get removed from the cache, while the working tree should be left alone — except that you've just removed all files from your working tree. Now they're removed from your index as well.

In other words, all changes, staged or unstaged, are gone, and your working tree is empty. Have a cry, checkout your files fresh from origin or remote, and redo your work. Curse the sadist who wrote these infernal lines; I have no clue whatsoever why anybody would want to do this.

---

**TL;DR: you just hosed everything; start over and use `git reset` from now on.**

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that the first of those command lines unconditionally deleted from the working copy all the files that are in git's staging area.  The second one unstaged all the files that were tracked but have now been deleted.  Unfortunately this means that you will have lost any uncommitted modifications to those files.

If you want to get your working copy and index back to how they were *at the last commit*, you can (**carefully**) use the following command:

```
git reset --hard
```

I say "carefully" since `git reset --hard` **will obliterate uncommitted changes in your working copy** and index.  However, in this situation it sounds as if you just want to go back to the state at your last commit, and the uncommitted changes have been lost anyway.

*Update: it sounds from your comments on Amber's answer that you haven't yet created any commits (since HEAD cannot be resolved), so this won't help, I'm afraid.*

As for how those pipes work: `git ls-files -z` and `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D -z` both output a list of file names separated with the byte `0`.  (This is useful, since, unlike newlines, `0` bytes are guaranteed not to occur in filenames on Unix-like systems.)  The program `xargs` essentially builds command lines from its standard input, by default by taking lines from standard input and adding them to the end of the command line.  The `-0` option says to expect standard input to by separated by `0` bytes.  `xargs` may invoke the command several times to use up all the parameters from standard input, making sure that the command line never becomes too long.

As a simple example, if you have a file called `test.txt`, with the following contents:

```
hello
goodbye
hello again
```

... then the command `xargs echo whatever < test.txt` will invoke the command:

```
echo whatever hello goodbye hello again
```

Comment: I never made any commits so it will say like can't resolve HEAD. What we do in such situations. Thanks a lot for explaining pipe in detail.

Comment: If you have just changed your git ignore and did git add --all to include a lot of files, DO NOT run git reset --hard to unstage them. THEY WILL BE DELETED!!

Comment: Uwaaahh!! Maybe you need to highlight the word **"carefully"**. I just saw these three words "git reset --hard" and all my unstaged files are...fufff!! gone!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to unstage all the changes use below command,

```
git reset --soft HEAD
```

In the case you want to unstage changes and revert them from the working directory,

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```