# How to remove files from git staging area?

Tags: git

I made changes to some of my files in my local repo, and then I did `git add -A` which I think added too many files to the staging area. How can I delete all the files from the staging area?

After I do that, I'll just manually do `git add "filename"`.

Comment: Hopefully you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505948/how-do-i-remove-a-single-file-from-the-staging-area-of-git-but-not-remove-it-fro

Comment: `git status` already tells you exactly what to do if you want to unstage files.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis git status isn't as helpful if you want to unstage a whole directory if it floods the terminal with output (such as node_modules)

Comment: In the future, instead of adding all, you may want to get comfortable with `git add -p` or `git add --patch` (they're the same). That flag allows you to interactively select which files or individual changes you want to stage -- you can then get a lot more finely grained with what work you include in the commit.

Comment: I've found it helpful to use a `git status` and then use the command `xargs git add`.  I can than select the files in the status (left click of the mouse) and then paste it using the right click of the mouse or <kbd>Shift-Insert</kdb>.  For a range of files, I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> and do a box selection using the mouse and then paste them as a group. At the end of each paste, I would press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and at the end of all pasting, I would press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to apply the files to the `git add` command.

Answer (score 1427, accepted):

You can unstage files from the index using

```
git reset HEAD -- path/to/file
```

Just like `git add`, you can unstage files recursively by directory and so forth, so to unstage everything at once, run this from the root directory of your repository:

```
git reset HEAD -- .
```

Also, for future reference, the output of `git status` will tell you the commands you need to run to move files from one state to another.

Comment: `$ git reset HEAD -- .` produced `fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.` Note that I never did any commit; its the first `git add` after `git init`

Comment: You can also use `git reset @`.

Comment: @alex Is it better than just plain `git reset`?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins `@` is synonymous with `HEAD`.

Comment: which is better git reset or git restore --staged

Comment: For newer versions of git, "git status" recommends using "git restore" command.  Please see answer by @norixxx

Comment: There is at least one case where `git status` will **not** tell you how to unstage a file: after a `git merge --no-commit --no-ff`. (git 2.30.1)

Comment: git reset HEAD -- . worked for me on a branch with no previous commits

Answer (score 570):

Use

```
git reset
```

to unstage all the staged files.

Comment: Can I ask how this differs to `git reset HEAD --` or is it simply a more succinct way of performing the same operation?

Comment: @ProNotion Reset uses `HEAD` by default. What's the purpose of those `--` in your `git reset HEAD --` ?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins it should have been followed by a full stop (period) and was taken from the example in the accepted answer.

Comment: @ProNotion Sorry I misunderstood you. `git reset HEAD -- .` is different in that it only resets files in the current directory and below while `git reset` resets all the files in the project.

Comment: actually I hop I had read this comment first, I kept trying solutions in previous comments but it was in vain, that command went quickly in one step @Antony Hatchkins

Answer (score 217):

Now at v2.24.0 suggests

```
git restore --staged .
```

to unstage files.

Comment: this is the recommended method by git itself for unstaging files

Comment: That will result in a (no branch), so

Comment: Can anyone verify or explain the above note by Hu XiXi: "no branch"?

Comment: Everyone here notes the "." argument as well as "<file>". That argument is just a common path reference. "./d1/d2" unstages all of the files in that path. This is great when you have a lot of changes for ./code or ./docs or ./configs that are unrelated, should be committed separately, and -oops- we were slow on commits and just did a single "add .".

Answer (score 172):

If you've already committed a bunch of unwanted files, you can unstage them *and* tell git to mark them as deleted (without actually deleting them) with

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

`--cached` tells it to remove the paths from staging and the index without removing the files themselves and `-r` operates on directories recursively. You can then `git add` any files that you want to keep tracking.

Comment: I suppose it is "git rm -- ."

Comment: there's a fatal error about not removing files with "git rm -- ."

Comment: @AlexMills I update my answer to mention the actual options for `rm` to unstage all files.

Comment: I tried this on a singular file like this: "git rm --cached my/file.java" and I see that file still in the staging area, but as deleted! @Max when you run this command are your files actually getting deleted or just un-staged? If you are not looking for that behavior I would go with answer.

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg thanks for pointing that out! `--cached` is really to stop tracking files that you've already committed. So the file isn't actually deleted, but git thinks it is. I've clarified this in my answer.

Answer (score 133):

Use the following to remove a specific file from the staging area:

```
git restore --staged <individual_file>
```

Or use the following to remove all the files that are currently staged:

```
git restore --staged .
```

In your git bash terminal after adding files to the staging area you can run a `git status` and the command is displayed for you above the current staged files:

```
$ git status 
On branch Releases/v1.1.1.x
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Releases/v1.1.1.x'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified: Source Code/Server/Server.sln

Changes not staged for commit:
...
```

Answer (score 53):

### **MUCH SIMPLIFIED ANSWER (git v2.23 and above)**

Below git command will remove all files from staging area

```js
git restore --staged .
```

***Or simply you can***

```
git restore -S .
```

**NOTE:** Run these commands from your project `root directory` and don't forgot the `.` (dot) at the end!

Comment: `git restore --staged .` did nothing. All of the staged files are still staged. `git version 2.40.1.windows.1`

Comment: @EdMorton The git restore command was introduced in Git version 2.23.0. The Git documentation indicates that there have been no changes to the git restore command from version 2.35.1 to 2.41.0

I recommend you to check the usage of this command on following link. 
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore

Comment: I ended up doing something different, I'm just saying that `git restore --staged .` did not unstage my files.

Comment: @EdMorton i just checked again on my mac and linux(ubuntu) and i can confirm both of the above command works. so nothing wrong with the command. you need to check your windows environment.

Comment: Not sure what there is to check and I'm not having any other problems using `git bash` on Windows.

Answer (score 43):

To remove all files from staging area use -
`git reset`
To remove specific file use -
`git reset "File path"`

Comment: Thank you for the time saving tip where I can remove just one of the files

Answer (score 37):

You could use

```
git reset HEAD
```

then add the specific files you want with

```
git add [directory/]filename
```

Comment: You can add -x parameter and ignored files will be removed too. It's useful if you mess up with your .gitignore and have something useful there (as in my case). (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)

Comment: With excess folders, `git status` will tell you *working directory clean* - lies! `git clean -df` did ths job, thanks.

Comment: Note that `git clean -df` will delete files permanently. On UNIX-like systems, it will call `unlink()` and your deleted files will not be recoverable.

Comment: The OP asks about unstaging the files. You advise him to delete the files. I'd suggest you to read about what the staging area is prior to answering.

Comment: Thank you for deleting my entire unsaved project.

Comment: The question was reedited some months AFTER I answered it. This can turn some answers invalid for the case.

Comment: @PavelRyzhov replaced "in" with "from" and removed "Thanks". Neither the title nor the idea of the question wasn't changed. Your answer answers another question. As for the asked question, it doesn't add anything relevant to other answers. I'd suggest you make your answer more compact and more to the point or delete it as it proves to be destructive to some people.

Comment: Ok. Shortened and cleaned.

Answer (score 26):

It is very simple:

1. To check the current status of any file in the current dir, whether it is staged or not:

   `git status`
2. Staging any files:

   `git add .` for all files in the current directory

   `git add <filename>` for specific file
3. Unstaging the file:

   `git restore --staged <filename>`

Answer (score 13):

If unwanted files were added to the staging area but not yet committed, then a simple reset will do the job:

```
$ git reset HEAD file
# Or everything
$ git reset HEAD .
```

To only remove unstaged changes in the current working directory, use:

```
git checkout -- .
```

Answer (score 10):

As noted in other answers, you should use `git reset`. This will undo the action of the `git add -A`.

**Note:** `git reset` is equivalent to `git reset --mixed` which does this

> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action. [ [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)  ]

Comment: .. and to remove a *single* file from staging area, you can do `git reset filenameToNotCommit`

Answer (score 5):

use

```
git reset HEAD
```

This will remove all files from staging area

Answer (score 4):

Use "`git reset HEAD <file>...`" to unstage fils

ex : to unstage all files

```
git reset HEAD .
```

to unstage one file

```
git reset HEAD nameFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the staging area in a few ways:

1. Reset HEAD and add all necessary files to check-in again as below:

   ```
    git reset HEAD ---> removes all files from the staging area
    git add <files, that are required to be committed>
    git commit -m "<commit message>"
    git push
   ```

Comment: What makes this answer different from the existing six answers?

Answer (score 0):

Remove directory from staging area!
git rm --cached <<repo/directory name>>

if this doesn't work use -f tag
git rm --cached <<repo/directory name>> -f

Answer (score 0):

None of these commands work for what I want to do. I want to uncommit changes that have not yet been pushed. I always thought that was 'unstaging', but none of the solutions above does this. Here's what does to this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Ship it.

Answer (score -9):

I tried all these method but none worked for me. I removed .git file using `rm -rf .git` form the local repository and then again did `git init` and `git add` and routine commands. It worked.

Comment: Reading the git docs is generally more rewarding than following the advice from https://xkcd.com/1597/ ;)

Comment: Maybe you had an integrity problem in your specific case and this was the option left, yet it's not recommended.

Comment: Please don't do this, you will destroy your entire git repo.