# How to undo the work after git add?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-revert, git-add

There are many questions about git, so I google for a while before I asked here. I've not find any useful info.

Just make it easy,

```
cat a.txt >> c.txt
git add .
cat b.txt >> c.txt
```

how to undo the last cat command.

Note here is just a simple to illustrate what I want, there are lot of modify before and after the git add.

The question may be duplicate, or the title is not proper, may someone helps?

Comment: Basically, `git checkout c.txt` will reset `c.txt` to its state in the index, which is the state you added when you did `git add .`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/52704/6521116  http://stackoverflow.com/a/52713/6521116

Comment: The question is asking how to discard STAGED changes (i.e. he did a git add).  The reference to the "duplicate" addresses the question of UNSTAGED (that are "not in the index") changes.  I agree that this question is a duplicate, but  to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730565/  and not to the link posted by poke.