# How to remove some files from commit checklist Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I would like to commit changes which I did in my AS project. But I see that changeslist contains `release` folder:

[image]

It means that I will commit workable `apk` file and some config files which were generated during building installer. I can also untick these files but when I will try to make commit at the next time I will see these files again. Maybe I can remove these files totally from my changes list and prevent its appearing at all next times. I think it happens because I tried some commands at the terminal and one command can add these files, I think it was:

`git commit --am`

So, how I can solve this problem without damaging all project?

### UPDATE:

Can I solve my problem with the command:

`git rm --app-release.apk` ?

Comment: you can add that to unversioned or git ignore files

Comment: @ManojPerumarath, how I can do it? at terminal?

Comment: i don't know how to do it with command, it's pretty easy to do with android studio tools

Comment: just delete the release  folder , and when generating signed apk , select different folder .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First Things first:

You can add a .gitignore file to your repository, via terminal, by the commands below:

1. In Terminal, navigate to the location of your Git repository.
2. Enter `touch .gitignore` to create a .gitignore file.

Second, you should pay attention that, If you already have a file checked in and you want to ignore it, Git will not ignore the file if you add a rule later. In those cases, you must untrack the file first, by running the following command in your terminal:

```
$ git rm --cached FILENAME
```

for more information on this follow https://help.github.com/en/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: Suppose if i have 10 branches and I want to remove the file from all of them and from the hsitory too. is it possible?

Comment: Sure! It is possible. At the moment, I can't remember how to do that. A tiny search will make you go... @AmanVerma

Answer (score 4):

First add the file/folder to your .gitignore file (In your case, the app-level one and not the project-level one)

Go to the Terminal in Android Studio and type in these commands:

`git rm -r the-directory-to-remove` In which case your `the-directory-to-remove` is the release folder.

The above command will remove the specified directory from git.

`git commit -m "Delete release folder"`

The above command commits the changes, you can change "Delete release folder" to whatever you like.

`git push origin <your-git-branch>`

The above command pushes the changes to Github (or BitBucket).

Now, if you want to delete the file from Github/BitBucket ONLY but not from the entire git filesystem, run `git rm -r --cached myFolder` instead of the first command.

Answer (score 3):

If  you have a gitignore file then add this line

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
*.aab

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
.idea/caches

# Keystore files
# Uncomment the following lines if you do not want to check your keystore 
files in.
#*.jks
#*.keystore

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json

# fastlane
fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output
fastlane/readme.md
```

or create a .gitignore file in your root folder of project

Comment: it doesn't work for me :( I backed up .gitignore file and created new one with related filetypes and right now I have toooooo much unversioned files

Comment: what means long gitignore file? I tried also to add some files at settings, and it didn't help me also

Comment: Do I have to invalidate cashes/restart AS after editing file?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko No need just rebuild

Comment: I can't reach my target :((( I deleted .gitignore from root and app folders, then created the new ones with your content and now I have so much unversioned files which I wouldn't like to commit

Comment: post that screenshot , unversioned files won't get commited @AndrewGoroshko

Comment: I thought similarly but I managed to remove files only by `git rm -r --cached path`

Answer (score 3):

you need to add those files in your ignored files under version control area in your android studio. For navigation go to

```
Open File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Ignored Files.
```

Add files those you don't want to commit or include. Another way of doing it like the other answer suggested to do it with .gradle tools.

[image]

Comment: i tried it and it didn't help me :( I still see these files

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko I think you already added these files to git. You have to remove them first and then add again in ignore files.

Comment: this option is not available now.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Remove file's from staging area using below command

> git reset HEAD file

[check this](https://clubmate.fi/git-removing-files-from-the-staging-area-and-the-tree/)

[similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19730687/7972699)

Step 2: add `release` folder and other generated file's to your `.gitignore`

Ref:

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using https://www.gitignore.io/ for generating `.gitignore` file for your android project and put it in your root folder of the project.

https://www.gitignore.io/api/android gives a headstart for your android project(Modify this according to your requirement. But for most cases this should be out-of-the-box solution).

Also, to add to the point. This is expected behaviour of `git` and not related anyway to android studio/android.

Answer (score 2):

For ex.if you want remove all files in package "**.idea**" - run command:

```
 git rm --cached -r .idea
```

`**"-r"**` - remove recursively all files in the folder.