# How to unstage a deleted file in git?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I did `git reset HEAD -- "*user*"` (to remove all "user" files from the staged area) but now git somehow thinks that I wanted to deleted a completely different file that I didn't even touch lately (the file is also still in my folder). `git status` now shows me:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    webpack.config.js
```

I don't want to delete this file. So I want to remove the deletion from the stage and also from the index.

I tried all of the following commands which I found here on StackOverflow but none of these worked... (I of course checked `git status` after each command but the deletion was still there):

```sh
git restore --staged webpack.config.js
git restore webpack.config.js

git reset HEAD webpack.config.js
git reset -- webpack.config.js

git checkout HEAD -- webpack.config.js
git checkout HEAD webpack.config.js 
git checkout -- webpack.config.js

git add webpack.config.js
git rm --cached webpack.config.js
```

At one point I also tried `git checkout .` which deleted all of my unstaged changes... (I was able to bring the changes back by issuing a `undo` command for each file in my IDE).

I also tried to unstage the deletion with SourceTree:

[image: SourceTree view]

But this is also not working.

So what's the right way to remove a file from the staged area (but keeping the changes)?

Comment: can you not simply strage that unstaged file again? Looks like it has been created and added and then staged so unstaging is for git technically deleting.

Comment: @TheFool I just did: `git add webpack.config.js` - still deleted.

Comment: I think what you wanted to say was `git rm --cached`. I am not sure where you are getting this `reset` usage.

Comment: So you said you've tried a bunch of commands but none worked.. did `git` say anything?

Comment: @matt I just did `git rm --cached webpack.config.js`, the file then additionally showed up under untracked files but also still as deleted in the stage area. So I also tried `git add webpack.config.js` again, it's gone under the untracked files but it's still showed as deleted.

Comment: @Paolo no, nothing

Comment: You say you "just did" it. I'm saying that this is what you should have done instead of saying `reset`. There is no point saying it _now_.

Comment: @matt Oh, sorry., I misread your comment. I got that `reset` usage from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19730687/3459910). I used that command because I was trying to find out the difference of `reset` and `restore`.

Comment: For this particular usage, there is no functional difference between running `git reset` or `git restore`. For other purposes there are differences. The `restore` command was new in Git 2.23, so any instructions written before its release will not use it.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence :

```
git checkout -- webpack.config.js
git add webpack.config.js
```

should have been enough

Comment: But that didn't work

Comment: That very much worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by clicking `stage all` and then `unstage all` again in SourceTree. The deletion is now gone.

Comment: That's not so much a solution as a backdoor workaround. In terms of git itself, we have no idea what you just did.

Comment: @matt I don't know what SourceTree is doing in the background there.

Comment: I know, but for that reason this is not a useful answer.

Comment: It seems likely that your IDE kept noticing every time you put the file back, and kept re-deleting it since you had told your IDE you wanted it deleted.