# How do you completely clear the files staged as a result of a "git add ."?

Tags: git, caching, staging

When trying to add files to push to a git repo, I accidentally added other folders, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to clear the staging queue.

I've tried `git reset`, but the files are still staged. I've tried `git rm --cached`, but I get

```
fatal: No pathspec was given. Which files should I remove?
```

I tried `git rm -r --cached`, but that also gives

```
fatal: No pathspec was given. Which files should I remove?
```

I can't find any working technique whatsoever across the internet, and would greatly appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

Comment: 1) Figure out which files comprise your actual change set, then 2) unstage any files _not_ in that list.  Run `git status` to get the complete list of all files.

Comment: What's staged after a reset is the checked-out version, no changes. Every commit is a complete snapshot.

Comment: Okay, I got only the folder I wanted pushed. All the red directories when using git status really threw me off.

Comment: @LeGEC `git reset` (without the ending dot) will also unstage everything.

Comment: @RomainValeri you are right, updating my comment

Comment: `git reset` should un stage everything, it's weird if it didn't do that in your case. `git restore -S -s HEAD .` will also work (the `.` is relevant, to indicate "all of the repo")

Comment: please try to do a "git status". Read the ENTIRE output and you will find out git litterally tells you what to do... unless you are using a very old version of git that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Git Reset .` as in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39454637/22836964) (Note the space before the period, this will restore ***all*** files).

Or `Git Restore --staged` as in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58830990/22836964). Either one should do the job.