# Why "git rm --cached" remove the up-to-date files?

Tags: git

I have a README.md in my local git repo. The local git repo has nothing staged and nothing changed in working tree. See below:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I run `git rm --cached -- README.md`, it says this:

```
$ git rm --cached -- README.md
rm 'README.md'
```

According to the `git help rm`:

> --cached
>
> Use this option to unstage and remove paths **only from the index**. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

There's no staged changes about README.md. So the staging area/index should contain nothing. Why is it still removed?

### ADD1

Based on @DietrichEpp's answer:

States exist at 3 places as git is concerned:

1. working tree
2. index
3. repo

Git decides what's `un-tracked` or `un-staged` by comparing 1 and 2;

Git decides what's `to-be-commited` by comparing 2 and 3;

`git reset` can be used to change state in 1 and/or 2.

Comment: More precisely, there's the `HEAD` commit (which should take the place of your item #3), then the index (your #2), then the work-tree (your #1). If you use `git status --short` these are compared left-to-right, pairwise. The index (and *only* the index) defines what is tracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index doesn't contain nothing, it contains whatever you are going to commit, including the files that are already part of the repo. Let's say that you run the following commands:

```
touch a.txt b.txt
git add a.txt b.txt
git commit
git rm --cached a.txt
git commit
```

When you first run `git add`, it adds `a.txt` and `b.txt` to the index. Then, `git commit` takes whatever is in the index and commits it.

The index still contains `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

When you `git rm --cached`, it removes `a.txt` from the index, but `b.txt` is still in the index. Then, `git commit` takes whatever is in the index (only `b.txt`) and commits it.  The `a.txt` file is still there, because `git rm --cached` doesn't touch the actual file, and neither does `git commit`.

Because the first commit contains `a.txt` and the second commit does not, this shows up as a deletion.

The main thing that `git status` does is show you the *difference* between the index and the actual files on disk. So if `git status` is empty, then all of the non-ignored files on disk are in the index, too.

Comment: I tried a bit more. It seems `index` holds all the tracked files. When I rm a file from index, it just turns into untracked. Not physically deleted from the file system. After I made the commit, it (README.md) just became one of the untracked files.

Comment: It's very interesting. If I use `reset` to set some file state in `index` to some other revsions, `git status` will tell me I have some `changes to be commited`. Actaully I change nothing to the working tree. Once I use `git add` to add the specific file and NOT run `git commit` yet, `git status` says I have nothing to commit. So it seems `git status` just blindly compares the content in index, the repo, and the working tree. It doen't care about the history.

Comment: That's right, `git status` doesn't care about the history.