# Remove all files for git commit?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undo “git add”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add)

I made the mistake of running:

```
git add .
```

Which added important things such as .bashrc. Even though I run:

```
git rm .
```

When I run:

```
git push project master
```

Everything still is added. I've even reinstalled git, but I am still pestered by this. A solution I found was to start over and remove all the files from the commit. Are there any other things I could do to remove all the files from the commit?

Comment: By the way, the "hard" way to solve it wouldn't have been re-installing git but deleting (`rm -rf`) your repository folder and cloning it again (assuming it's a clone of a remote repo).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `git reset` to unstage changes, or even `git reset --hard HEAD~` to blow away the most recent commit (careful with that one, it will not even keep your changes around.)

See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: It doesn't work. How I know that is I ran git log --pretty=format: --name-status | cut -f2- | sort -u and it still displayed all of the files.

Comment: If your changes get pushed you've already committed them.

Answer (score 10):

Use `git reset`.