# Commit changes only in one directory in Git

Tags: git

I'm using Git 1.7.4.1 on Mac 10.6.6.  From the command line, how do I commit changes in only a single directory?  I added the directory by doing:

```
git add my-dir
```

but doing

```
git commit -a
```

brings up a list of all changes in my repo, and I only want to commit and push changes from `my-dir`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Omit the `-a` option. Then `git` will commit only the files that you staged with `git add`.

You can also try committing the directory without staging with `git commit my-dir`.

Comment: If I do the second thing you say (try committing without staging), which changes will be committed?

Comment: In that case, @Stefan, "the commit will ignore changes staged in the index, and instead record the current content of the listed files (which must already be known to Git)," says [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).

Comment: Also if you have staged some excluded files, you can unstage them with: $ git reset -- <path> and then $ git commit -m 'msg' and tthen $ git push

Answer (score 83):

Why does no one mention you can simply

```
git commit -m 'message' -- my-dir
```

It seems to me the OP isn't used to / doesn't like to use the staging area directly. This approach is also a lot safer to recommend without further context, because chances are that a defaault commit (of everything that's staged) will

- commit more than just my-dir if it already had been staged
- will produce confusing results when the OP is not used to managing the staging area explicitly (because the working tree can have gotten out of synch with the index)

Comment: I believe I *did* mention that — at least the part of it that was relevant to the question. (Whether the commit message is included in the command line or prompted for later is a separate issue from the topic at hand, which was how to commit a specific directory without committing everything else.)

Comment: Oops. I missed it (the `-a` talk threw me off track?). I might subconsciously scan for the **`--`** token. (_oh and the commit message thing is just habit :)_)

Answer (score 20):

Hmm, odd. The following should work. Assuming you have nothing staged.

```
git add my-dir
git commit -m "Commiting first revision of my-dir folder. Very exciting feature!"
git push origin master
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question, but that's probably my own fault :) I rewrote my answer. I hope it is to more satisfaction.

Comment: Well, that's a little bit clearer. I still don't get why you are '_yelling_' that it must. In fact, that will only be correct once you limit the scope of the `commit` as well (since you cannot know what else is staged already)

Comment: Ok, I follow you. Was not my intention to yell, it was just to emphasize the word. Replaced with should. And yes of course, I assumed that nothing else was added to the index.

Answer (score 12):

**Basic**

```
git add -- ./myfolder
git commit -m'my comment' -- ./myfolder
```

**With more files and dirs**

```
git add -- ./myfolder1 ./myfolder2./some/random/file.txt
git commit -m'cool' -- ./myfolder1 ./myfolder2 ./some/random/file.txt
```

**What I was looking for git bare repo**

```
git --git-dir=path/to/my/repo --work-tree=path/to/my/working/tree add -- ./myfolder
git --git-dir=path/to/my/repo --work-tree=path/to/my/working/tree commit -m'my comment' -- ./myfolder
```

Remember to quote paths with spaces or crazy chars

Answer (score 4):

Just stage the folder using `git add` as you specified, and do a commit without the `-a` option: `git commit -m "Committing stuff"`. The `-a` option means commit all files which have been modified, even if they aren't staged.

Answer (score 4):

Do it all in one command:

```
git commit -- my-dir
```

Comment: Same [answer from sehe](/a/5862894/938111) is two days older and provides some explanations. Same [answer from user6120452](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36247058/938111) provides useful details.

Answer (score 2):

You will commit any changes in the "staging area"; you can see these with `git status`.

the `-a` flag in `git commit -a`, according to the man page, tells git to roughly "stage all files that have been modified or deleted, but not new files you have not told git about" - **this is not what you want**

**the lesson is to be aware of what command line options do**

To fix this, the first thing you want to do is, according to [How to undo 'git add' before commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add) , to unstage all the files you've accidentally added with the `commit -a` option. According to that answer, you must perform the command `git rm -r --cached .`, and now your changes should still be there, but nothing is staged.

Now you can do `git add my-dir` like you did before. Then you can do `git commit` (WITHOUT THE `-a`)