# How to filter commit files?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have 2 folders in my project say APJ and EMEA and files can be committed from both the folders but I have a scenario where I want to trigger only APJ files or EMEA files.

I tried with only changes option but it didn't help.
Changes:

```
- DB/APJ/**/*
```

For example, My commit contains 2 files, one from APJ folder and one from EMEA folder. I want files from APJ folder only. How do I filter my commit files?

```
 Commit : abcs123
 File1 :  DB/APJ/test.sql
 File2 : DB/EMEA/test2.sql
```

Is there a way to add some settings in the .yml file? The expected result is to get APJ files and EMEA files separately even when I commit them together.

Comment: What has this to do with `c#`?

Comment: I am using gitlab API with C# code to get commit details.. I was thinking is there a way to filter commit files at API level?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? to commit files from specific folder only? or to view committed files from specific folder only? it is not clear in your question.

Comment: To view specific files from commit.

Comment: To do this, you should create an application layer over the gitlab api. I do not see a valid reason for gitlab api to have it already available as an option. BTW what gitlab api endpoint are you using now to get the commit files?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by adding files from the specific folder (APJ) before commit.

```
git add DB/APJ
git commit -m "my changed files in APJ"
```

See this post as well:
[Commit changes only in one directory in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862233/commit-changes-only-in-one-directory-in-git)

Comment: But i dont have control over commit. User can commit files from any folder. I need to filter them based on the project path

Comment: the "user" is to decide what is staged (with git add command) before commit. so, the user is to take care what is added.

Answer (score 0):

Only staged files can be committed.So you can do this by

```
git add DB/APJ/
git commit -m "files in DB/APJ are changed"
```

Moreover, if you want to ignore files from specific folder you can add those folders in git ignore.

1. Create a file named .gitignore in your project's directory. (if it is not exists in your repository yet)
2. To Ignore directories/Folders, just write the directory_name/folder_name/file_name into the file (with a slash appended):

> ```
>  DB/APJ/
> ```

for more information check [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

git show -m -1 --name-only --pretty=format: --stat --relative

By using above command we can filter commit files, It will only return the folder specific files 
If i am in APJ folder and execute this command then i will get only APJ folder files from the commit. Note that this commit can contain files from APJ and EMEA folders. Hope everyone is able to understand :)