# Commit specific files from one branch to another

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have two branches `master` and `testing`.

I only want to commit two folders from the testing branch. And leave the rest intact.

For example:

`master`

> index.js

> source

> var

`testing`

> index.js[*]

> source[*]

> var[*]

**After commit the changes from `testing` into `master`:**

`master`

> index.js

> source[*]

> var[*]

Comment: in git you need to touch a file to upload the folder

Comment: @matmahnke Could you write to me a little bit more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862233/commit-changes-only-in-one-directory-in-git
I believe that answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
git checkout testing -- <path/>
```