# Does `git reset HEAD file` also check out the file?

Tags: git

I mistakenly added a directory to git and when I followed the tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add) to undo the add by doing `git reset HEAD <file>`, I was horrified to discover that the current working copy of one of the files, which has lots of changes (work!) in it, **reverted back** to the previous version!

As a result I lost several hours worth of work... :((

I thought that `git reset HEAD <file>` only "removes it from the current index **[without changing anything else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add/348234#348234)**. What did I miss?

Is `git reset HEAD <file>` supposed to also **check out** the file from HEAD?

How can I minimize the chances of something like this happening again in the future?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only `git checkout -- <file>` should have reverted the files in their previous stats.
`git reset HEAD <file>` should only unstage the file, not revert its content.

Comment: OK, could a `git rm -r <directory>` that I did earlier (and git reported that this operation failed) explain what happened?

Comment: git reset HEAD  --hard will reverted the files in their previous stats :]

Answer (score 2):

`git reset` unstages files from index. Maybe you added `--hard` option or used `git checkout` afterwards?

Quoting the git-reset manpage:

> git reset [-q] [<commit>] [--] <paths>...
>              This form resets the index entries for all  to their state at . (It does not affect the working tree, nor the current branch.)

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand you correctly that `git reset HEAD <file>` is **NOT** supposed to do what I experienced? i.e. it was something else that I did that reverted the file back?

Comment: @Eternal Learner - Yes, perhaps reading man git-reset would be a good thing to do :)

Comment: I read it countless times before. Apparently it didn't help me this time. :(