# Untrack files from git temporarily

Tags: git, github, repository

I have setup a local git on my machine. When I initialized git, I added pre-compiled libs and binaries. However, now during my development I don't want to check in those files intermittently. I dont want to remove these files from repo. Is there any way to not keep a track of these files till I complete my development. (I think I can not use .gitignore as it works only for those files which are not in git. I want to temporarily disable tracking of files.)

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/936249/11343

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: can i commit a file and ignore the content changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/git-can-i-commit-a-file-and-ignore-the-content-changes)

Answer (score 870, accepted):

[git update-index](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) should do what you want

This will tell git you want to start ignoring the changes to the file
`git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file`

When you want to start keeping track again
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file`

[Github Documentation: update-index](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)

Comment: Finally a command that actually works for my accidentally-committed-dev-file, thanks :)

Comment: Why not git rm -r --cached <file> ?

Comment: @Ehsan it seems `git rm --cached` will lead to a deletion of the local copies on other machines, where the same branch is checked out, on their next pull. See http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/git/untrack-files-in-git-repos-without-deleting-them/ and especially the discussion below it.

Comment: That wouldn't be an issue if the file was a generated file produced by a build though, would it?  I have a situation where a `.chw` file (some sort of index for a windows help CHM file) was being tracked, I could presumably `git rm -r --cached Help\foo.chw`, right?  Although that might nuke the file on another build machine, it would be regenerated on the next build.

Comment: Not working for me, when I make changes to the file it's still added to included changes. I could exclude, but then at some point it'll probably be added in accidentally.

Comment: assume-unchanged wasn't meant for this purpose. Might want to read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097368/git-ignore-vs-exclude-vs-assume-unchanged)

Comment: What is the outcome if another dev modifies + commits their version of the file, pushes it to remote repository and then the dev with "--assume-unchanged" flag applied on the file pulls those changes? Does the file get updated with latest changes from remote, remains as modified or creates a conflict since they now differ?

Comment: @Appy so should .git/info/exclude be used instead of using this as an "ignore mechanism"?

Comment: In case you want to untrack a directory : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288212/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-on-directory

Comment: `assume-unchanged` makes Guthub Desktop (git UI app) unstable (latest version as of now).

Answer (score 357):

you could keep your files untracked after

```
git rm -r --cached <file>
```

add your files with

```
git add -u
```

them push or do whatever you want.

Comment: That is actually the right answer according to: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Comment: `git rm --cached .DS_Store`  then it prints `rm '../.DS_Store'` And the local file is deleted??!  (`git version 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63)`)

Comment: Got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919121/why-are-there-2-ways-to-unstage-a-file-in-git

Comment: What does the `-r` option do? Does the whole command unstages the change and remove the file also from the repo or the folder structure ? Is it a recursive option ?

Comment: the -r flag recursivelly unstages and remove from the index; The work tree is kept unchanged.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer because this will remove the file in source. The OP wants to ignore local changes of that file, not remove tracking for it altogether

Comment: i can't remove the files from source please show me how.

Comment: WARNING: it will remove the files you want untrack as well. Solution is to copy all the files somewhere, and copy them back after the commit.

Answer (score 117):

```
git rm --cached
```

However, you shouldn't be committing compiled binaries and external dependancies in the first place.  Use a tool like Bundler to pull those in instead.

Comment: Dont forget -r option (recursive) for directories: git rm -r --cached

Answer (score 66):

Use following command to untrack files

```
git rm --cached <file path>
```

Answer (score 12):

Not an answer to the original question. But this might help someone.

To see the changes you have done (**know which files are marked as --assume-unchanged**)

```
git ls-files -v
```

The resulted list of files will have a prefix with one character (ex : H or h)
If it is a lowercase (i.e. h) then the file was **marked --assume-unchanged**

Comment: So use `git ls-files -v | grep "^h "` to see just the `--assume-unchanged` ones.

Comment: If you need something more Windows-friendly: `powershell "git ls-files -v |? {$_ -cmatch '^h '}"` ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

The git-book mentions this in section 2.4: "Undoing Things".  Basically, what you have to do is reset the state of the index for some files back to the HEAD state, that is to the state of the latest checkout (or commit).  This undoes staging the file to the current index.  The command for this task is `git reset`.[1]

So, the command you have to execute is:

```
git reset HEAD /path/to/file
```

The newer versions of git (I believe since 1.6 or so) gives this command (and many more) as a tip when executing `git status`.  These versions are very user-friendly.  A personal tip: if you are only staging a few files, use `git add -i`.  This will launch the interactive staging tool, which makes thing particularly easy.  Also, I highly recommend reading the book, as it is very explicit on the use of git in practical situations.

[1] http://www.git-scm.com/book

Comment: I agree that `git reset [file]` is the most straightforward way to unstage files.

Comment: undoing and untracking are different things

Comment: In this case, using `git reset` will not undo changes to the file. It will instead untrack the file, leaving the changes intact.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming that you are asking how to remove **ALL** the files in the build folder or the bin folder, Rather than selecting each files separately.

You can use this command:
`git rm -r -f /build\*`
Make sure that you are in the parent directory of the build directory.
 
This command will, recursively "delete" all the files which are in the bin/ or build/ folders. By the word delete I mean that git will pretend that those files are "deleted" and those files will not be tracked. The git really marks those files to be in delete mode.

Do make sure that you have your .gitignore ready for upcoming commits.
[Documentation : git rm](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `assume-unchanged` is `skip-worktree`. The latter has a different meaning, something like "Git should not track this file. Developers can, and are encouraged, to make local changes."

In your situation where you do not wish to track changes to (typically large) build files, `assume-unchanged` is a good choice.

In the situation where the file should have default contents and the developer is free to modify the file locally, but should not check their local changes back to the remote repo, `skip-worktree` is a better choice.

Another elegant option is to have a default file in the repo. Say the filename is `BuildConfig.Default.cfg`. The developer is expected to rename this locally to `BuildConfig.cfg` and they can make whatever local changes they need. Now add `BuildConfig.cfg` to `.gitignore` so the file is untracked.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849) which has some nice background information in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all Untrack files. Try this terminal command

```
 git clean -fdx
```

Comment: It will remove files from disk and not from git history.

Comment: thanks, you could remove many of our files successfully. congratulation

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
git rm -r --cached file_to_git_ignore
```

Then go to your `gitignore` file
and add `path_to_file_to_git_ignore`

Good luck