# GIT -- Exclude / Ignore Files from commit

Tags: git, content-management-system, gitignore, filefilter

I need to ignore files in git!  I don't think ignore is the right word actually; I want the files to be in git, but I don't want to be able to commit changes to them.  This may seem like a weird thing to some, but there are many, many instances that I need this functionality.  The one instance I need it for now is when using git with a CMS; the CMS won't work without files that it is constantly changing, but I don't want those files to ever be committed after the initial commit. (This is very easy to do with SVN and Tortoise).

WorkFlow:

1. Get All Files needed to run the app.
2. Ignore specified directories / files when committing.

Here is what I've tried:

1. `.gitignore` -- the files never enter git.  If the file is already in
   cache the .gitignore file doesn't do anything.
2. `/.git/info/exclude` -- same problem as .gitignore, but only for
   the local repo.
3. Branching -- master => LocalIgnores => WorkingBranch.  When the
   Working branch is merged with master, the changes made from
   LocalIgnores end up in master.  Also, when you checkout one of the
   new branches, the deleted files get deleted instead of ignored.
4. Thirdparty File Structure -- Thirdparty directory on the root
   node that holds a copy of all important thirdparty files so they can
   be copied into the working directory that utilizes the .gitignore
   file. (This one works, but there has to be an easier / better
   solurtion).

Comment: @Albireo manojlds' duplicate is more appropriate

Answer (score 96):

Here  is my answer from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git/6964322#6964322).

> [git update-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git/6964322#6964322) should do what you want
>
> This will tell git you want to start ignoring the changes to the file
>   `git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file`
>
> When you want to start keeping track again
>   `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file`

Comment: Awesome.  That did it.  I created a couple of bat files, IgnoreLocally.bat and UnIgnoreLocally.bat, that run from a .LocalIgnore file.   One click is much easier than copy&paste tons of files.  Thanks For the help.   Now to get tortoise to include it into their stuff!

Comment: Why don't you close it as a duplicate, rather than quoting from your answer? There are so many questions on this very thing. It all just becomes noise for future users.

Comment: @manojlds  I didn't know there was a way to flag a duplicate...  Are you supposed to flag: needs attention->other->than write in "duplicate"?

Comment: @Andy - There is a `close` next to left of the flag. Choose Exact Duplicate in that.

Comment: @manojlds I don't have that [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) yet.

Comment: @Andy - I am sorry, but it is pretty bad that some one with 1.5k rep can't vote to close!

Comment: @Andy - you could still do the Alternatives to closing. Also, I have already voted to close and you will see a comment with a link to the duplicate post.

Comment: Actually, don't close this yet...  This isn't a very good solution; rather it is incomplete.  There has to be a way to avoid running this every time you switch between branches, pull, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use a `pre-commit` hook. See `git help hooks` for details.

- This is harder to set up: you have to write a shell script to express exactly what you want to allow or disallow, which probably means you need to have a fairly good grasp of git.
- It's more permanent and flexible: with tricks like `git update-index` you can accidentally forget to run it, etc. But once you set up a hook, you never have to worry about it again.

Like the other tricks suggested, hooks don't automatically get propagated between repositories, but you **can** check them in as regular files and have everyone link them into `.git/hooks`.

Comment: you just miss some kind of example .