# git - ignoring commited files and switch branch

Tags: git

I have local repo and remote, say "upstream". In remote repo some basic configs say "file1.txt" and "file2.txt", I pull changes to branch "some_branch", and typed:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file1.txt
git update-index --assume-unchanged file2.txt
```

to allow modify this files, add some changes with my local changes, which I do not want to commit.

After that in "upstream" was added branch "somefeature"

```
fetch upstream somefeature:somefeature
```

and try:

```
$git checkout somefeature
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

$git checkout -f somefeature 
error: Entry 'file1.txt' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

then I try:

```
$git stash 
No local changes to save

$git stash -u
No local changes to save

$git update-index --no-assume-unchanged .
Ignoring path
```

also I tried "--skip-worktree", but unsuccessfully also.

So, how I can skip local changes whan use "add" or "commit -a", but be able to change branch, and  apply this hidden changes to unother branches, created not from current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stash everything try:

```
git stash save --all --no-keep-index
```

Comment: but when I come back to first branch, I can't restore state, when I use "git stash apply", it say "Could not restore untracked files from stash
"