# untracked files still appear in git status

Tags: git

I have untracked some folders and files by using .git/info/exclude :

```
doc
*.txt
doc/*.txt
doc/somefile.txt
```

But git status says it is still tracked :

```
$ git st
# On branch dev
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   doc/somefile.txt
```

Other weird thing is that `ls-files` shows it is untracked :

```
$ git ls-files --ignored --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
doc/somefile.txt
$ touch /tmp/xxx
$ git ls-files --ignored --exclude-from=/tmp/xxx
$
```

I am on git version 1.8.1.5

So I conclude I may misunderstand something or do something wrong. Any idea please ?

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are locally ignoring files that are in the repository, you need to tell git that you  are ignoring them

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <files to forget>
```

Comment: This is the right answer. @lalebarde, I can add you are not `untracking` the files, you are ignoring them. They are already tracked, therefore you have to follow @Abizern's advice to let git forget them. Check [this explanation](http://source.kohlerville.com/2009/02/untrack-files-in-git/) to know why `update-index` is a better solution than `rm --cached`

Comment: That command was never meant to solve this type of problem, and using it as such is considered a bad idea by the developers of git. It was meant as a way to improve performance in some situations. Git will take that as a promise that the file won't be changed underneath it, but that won't be at all true in this case.  Using `git stash` after this has been done is likely to lead to the local changes being lost.  See the thread around http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/225308 . There may  be problems with this in other cases as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `git rm --cached <file>`. This doesn't remove the file from your working directory, but it removes it from the `git cache` so it'll now be included by the .`gitignore`.

Comment: He isn't using .gitignore, he's using .git/info/exclude which is the local repository exclusion file.

Comment: Ah, true. He did say 'untrack' rather than 'ignore' though, so it depends on what he's trying to do with the files.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file(s) is currently beeing tracked, you need to tell `git`to forget about them before ignoring them.

`git rm --cached doc/somefile.txt`

Comment: No, that will delete the files, not ignore them.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot the `--cached` flag.