# Untracked ignored files still appear in git status

Tags: git

I know there are similar questions, but none of those solutions worked for me, hence creating a new question.

I have the following `.gitignore` section:

```
#generated sources in tfliteparser/tflite
tfliteparser/tflite/
kernels/native_funcs.cpp
```

However, when I run `git status`, both the file and the folder appear in the untracked files section:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../.DS_Store
        kernels/native_funcs.cpp
        network_summary.dat
        tfliteparser/tflite/
```

I am assuming, that since these objects are in the untracked section, they were never added to the index, right? Why do they appear then?

What I have tried:

```
git rm --cached kernels/native_funcs.cpp
```

This gives:

```
fatal: pathspec 'kernels/native_funcs.cpp' did not match any files
```

However, this file is there. If I `ls` it, OS sees it. 
I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271706/untracked-files-still-appear-in-git-status). Same result.

I know for a fact, that `.gitignore` file gets loaded since if I add `network_summary.dat` file to it, it gets ignored.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Does `git check-ignore -v kernels/native_funcs.cpp` show anything useful?

Comment: empty output :(

Comment: `git check-ignore -v -n kernels/native_funcs.cpp` returns `::      kernels/native_funcs.cpp`

Comment: Does `git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep -i 'kernels/native_funcs.cpp'` print anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `../.DS_Store` I see that the current directory is not the root of the repository. Your ignore patterns contain slashes so they match only at the directory level where your `.gitignore` resides. If the `.gitignore` is at the root of the repo your patterns don't match.

To make them match either prefix them with the subdirectory name or with an asterisk:

```
# .gitignore
<subdir>/tfliteparser/tflite/
*/kernels/native_funcs.cpp
```

---

```
$ git rm --cached kernels/native_funcs.cpp
fatal: pathspec 'kernels/native_funcs.cpp' did not match any files
```

This means `kernels/native_funcs.cpp` is not in the index (the file was not `git add`ed). `git rm --cached` only removes from index, not files.