# ErrorException in Cpdf.php line 3855: Undefined index: at barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

I am using laravel 5.2, The dompdf runs fine at localhost but when moved to AWS it keeps showing `ErrorException in Cpdf.php line 3855: Undefined index:`, in this line (3855) has font variable.

Sample code :

```
$html = "<h2>Hello</h2>";
PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
```

I can not set `'currentFont' => 'sans-serif'` at `setOptions` due to no options in barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. so how can I solve currentFont issue.

Localhost - Windows - Runs fine.

AWS - Linux - Error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Error solved by delete `dompdf_font_family_cache.php` file from `storage/fonts`
and let the renderer regenerate the cache.

Comment: Depending on your Laravel version, this file can be at `public/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.php` . Look there and delete the file to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I also recommend to ignore files in "storage/fonts" on Git. Here's [how to implement gitignore files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757964/4494207).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on the Linux machine.
The error shown was

> Undefined index: application/third_party/dompdf/lib/fonts\Times-Roman

If you observe the Directory separator before the font name '\' is not compatible in Linux environment. This path separator is hardcoded in the **dompdf_font_family_cache.php** file found in **../dompdf/lib/fonts** folder.

Open the file in the editor and replace '\' with '/'. Save the changes. The code will start working.