# .gitignore not ignoring .rubocop.yml file

Tags: git, gitignore

I have just added .rubocop.yml file to my project and added it to `.gitignore` file but when I do `git status` it appears as modified. I have never added this file to my repository. Why is `.gitignore` not ignoring this file?

#### project

app/
config/
.rubocop.yml

#### .gitignore

.rubocop.yml

Other files are ignored fine, for example, I also tried adding `tags` file to the root of the project and adding it to .gitignore and it works.

Why is `.gitignore` not ignoring `.rubocop.yml` file?

Comment: .gitignore only applies to files that have not been added. If the status shows as "modified" then it has already been added, and .gitignore does not apply to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19663093/2864740 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/2864740

Comment: I now checked again and indeed I added the file previously to the repo. My bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Commit your project first, then do `git rm --cached .rubocop.yml`. It shouldn't be included in your repository the next time you commit