# Incorrect path for Pods-testAppTests/Pods-testAppTests.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file

Tags: react-native, github, cocoapods

So I recently uploaded my react-native project on GitHub, then cloned it back to see how it will build(did it for first time... yeah). And on react-native run-ios I got a repetitive error:  "react-native-app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-testAppTests/Pods-testAppTests.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "testAppTests" in project "testApp") (in target 'testAppTests' from project 'testApp')
I found a solution, where this:

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

helped me as the project then built and ran correctly.
So my question is, how to upload it to GitHub in a way so it builds always correctly after cloning it?

Update

Checking and editing .gitignore solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is linked to files which have been added/committed, while they should have been ignored, private and local only (not uploaded to GitHub)

Check your .gitignore: here is [one for ReactNative](http://gitignore.io/api/reactnative), as explained in "[Creating a `.gitignore` for a Clean React Repository](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/creating-gitignore-for-clean-react-repository)", blog post written by **[Parker Johansen](https://www.pluralsight.com/authors/parker-johansen)**.

---

Then, assuming you don't have any pending  changes/work in progress, you can, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757964/6309), apply your new `.gitignore` to your existing repository:

```
cd /path/to/local/cloned/repo
# create your .gitignore
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
git push
```

Finally, clone it again, and see if it compiles better.

---

The OP adds in the comments:

> I found that folder 'Pods' doesn't exist on GitHub, that's why this error occurs, how can I add it to my /ios folder on Github correctly

I advise to check if there is a .gitignore rule which would ignore said folder:

```
git check-ignore -v Pods/aFile_inside_Pods
```

Comment: Well, it's not a .gitignore problem, I found that folder 'Pods' doesn't exist on GitHub, that's why this error occurs, how can I add it to my /ios folder on Github correctly?

Comment: @Oleksii Can you check if that folder is not already ignored, with `git check-ignore -v Pods\aFile_inside_Pods`?

Comment: yup it found it # CocoaPods
/ios/Pods/, should I just remove this from .gitignore and then push?

Comment: @Oleksii Yes, provided you git add the Pods folder content, commit and push