# How to publish Delphi project on Github?

Tags: delphi, github

I've written a small VCL program using Delphi CE. I want to publish the source code incl. forms on Github but I'm not sure which parts are essential to include in the repository so that others can load it in their IDE and compile it.

Comment: You need to post the .dpr, .pas and .dfm files at a minimum.

Comment: Exclude `*.~*` (last backup of a file being saved), `*.dcu` when their `*.pas` files exist, and `*.exe` when its `*.dpr` exists. But it doesn't hurt to publish all the files. Look at [other projects](https://github.com/search?q=delphi) which files they publish.

Comment: Include *.dproj and include *.fmx if it's a multi-platform project.

Comment: There is a list of Delphi file extensions and whether to include them in source control in the Delphi Wiki https://delphi.fandom.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you to use default .gitignore file for Delphi of Github. By this way you can be sure that all required files will be posted and all unnecessary files to compile will be excluded.

The file is here:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Delphi.gitignore

If you have an existing repository and want to add a gitignore file, have a look at here: [Apply .gitignore on an existing repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663093/apply-gitignore-on-an-existing-repository-already-tracking-large-number-of-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can also exclude this files:

*.~*
*.dsm
*.ddp
*.map
*.rsm
*.dcu
*.tds
*.local
*.identcache
*.dsk
*.stat
*.tvsconfig

Exclude too the content of directories:

__history
__recovery

Comment: Useful list. I also exclude `*.dcr` and the `~` files are excluded with `*.~*` (but this might be the same). Recommend putting excluded files alphabetically to simplify maintainence!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, some commonsense advice:

- Put whatever minimum set of files you think you need into git
- Download yourself (into a separate folder)
- See if the project builds
- If it fails, add the missing file(s) and repeat