# How to keep a version of a file fixed on github

Tags: git, github

I want to upload a project to GitHub, but one of the source files in the project must be unchanged, that is, the first version on GitHub must stay the same, regardless the modifications that developers make on their local file versions. Do any one realize how to do that?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files#ignoring-versioned-files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Untrack files from git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git)

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1: ignore it locally

Once you've added a file, `git` tracks it, even if it is in `.gitignore`. You can do things locally to ensure that you won't accidentally commit it, such as

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file.txt
```

However, you would have to ensure that all of your collaborators also do this, which is difficult.

### Option 2: make a template

Instead, I think a better strategy is to make a "template" that people can use to start off their often changing file.

For example, let's say that the file is a configuration file, `local.conf`. This file contains things like passwords and directories that are specific to a machine, so you wouldn't want to add those things to a repository. But, in order to have a valid `local.conf` file, you need to know the structure of that file.

Instead of committing `local.conf` and letting people change it, make a template file `local.conf.template`. Add `local.conf` to `.gitignore`, so that everyone's `local.conf` will never be committed. Then, in your `README`, instruct your collaborators to do

```
cp local.conf.template local.conf
```

and edit it from there.

Comment: Option 2 is definitely better. Option 1 is error prone and pretty hacky.

Comment: Thank you, very instructive. I will probably us option 2.