# Git status not clean after untracking a file

Tags: git

I've untracked a file using this command:

```
git rm --cached source/html/weekend-message.html
```

This is the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/425275) on Stack Overflow. After that, my git status looked like this:

[image]

I wasn't sure what to do now (I want a clean status), so I continued looking and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410794/425275) and performed this command:

```
git reset HEAD source/html/weekend-message.html
```

Now my git status looks like this:

[image]

I am very confused. I just want to untrack this file and have an **empty git status** after that. How do I do that?

---

**Update:** After performing the commands suggested in VonC’s answer below:

```
git rm --cached source/html/weekend-message.html
git commit -m "delete source/html/weekend-message.html"
```

my git status looks like this:

[image]

Git status still isn't clean :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have:

- committed (in order to record the deletion)
- added that file to your .gitignore, add and commit that change.

Since you have reset that file (undoing the deletion recorded in the index), you can try again:

```
git rm --cached source/html/weekend-message.html
git commit -m "delete source/html/weekend-message.html"
```

Then:

- add the file to the `.gitignore` file (you will see that is disappear immediately from the `git status` output)
- add and commit that `.gitignore` modification (second commit there)

---

Note: as suggested below in the comments, you can make just one commit:

- `git rm --cached source/html/weekend-message.html`
- add the file to the `.gitignore` file (you will see that is disappear immediately from the `git status` output), `git add .gitignore`. Note: now you get a proper git status, ready to be commited: [image]
- `git commit -m "delete and ignore source/html/weekend-message.html"`

---

Note that to **ignore a file locally** (as opposed to record its deletion in the history of the repo), you can use:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- yourFile
```

Not commit needed there, and the file remains in the history.

See more at "[Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309)".

Comment: I've performed these commands, but git status still isn't clean.

Comment: Btw are you saying that 2 commits are required to perform this property? (`rm --cached`, then commit the deletion, then update .gitignore, and finally commit the updated .gitignore)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes, but as soon as you add that file to the .gitignore, it should disappear from the status. I have edited the answer to make the two commits more visible.

Comment: Wow! I am a Git n00b, but having 2 commits in the history - "untrack foo" and "update .gitignore" - seems stupid. Is it really not possible to perform all this in a single commit?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas absolutely, that is actually a good idea. I was just breaking down the steps.

Comment: Instead of using an ignore file, if this is temporary (you might want to untrack the file and keep it around for reference, but not need an exception forever), just ignore that 'untracked files' section, or use `$ git status -uno` if you really want a "clean status".

Comment: I've added the proper screenshot. Hallelujah!