# How to untrack or uncommit files before commit on git having white-sapce

Tags: git

I merged some files with my local repository that I pull from git after merge local file.How can I untracked or uncommitted those file having white space.

```
Here is clearance 

local-set up
app/index.php - whitespace
comm/stle.csss - whitespace

Git repository on local 
app/index.php 
comm/stle.css

 github : github.com
```

Comment: First [Delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-can-i-delete-a-file-from-git-repo) these files from Git repo

Then [Untrack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git) these files.

Comment: So do you want to remove unnecessary white space from the files?