# How do we uncheck folders and all its subfolders and its contents in its subfolders from git

Tags: git

From this discussion,

[Untrack files from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git)

We know that we could uncheck some local files from Git. What if we want to uncheck everything inside a folder including all things its sub-folders. And all things that will be generated in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're talking about with "uncheck", but let's say you're talking about **Untracking**

Here's how to do that

From the root directory of the project:

```
git rm -r --cached folder_to_untrack
echo "/folder_to_untrack" >> .gitignore
```

This will add remove from git index `folder_to_untrack` and every subentry. Adding it to gitignore will prevent it to be shown in `Untracked files` sections from `git status` and to be added by mistake using `git add`