# Git tracking a file that shouldn't be

Tags: git, github

I have this repo on GitHub: https://github.com/liquid600pgm/exCircuit/tree/a2.0-new-pins

I am using GitHub Desktop for commiting to the repo, and for some reason it just really, really wants to track an unwanted file. This behavior also applies to git itself.

My `.gitignore` contains this line:

```
data/pinned.exc
```

But that file is tracked for some reason. I don't want it to be tracked, because it contains factory settings, and I have my own settings, but the repo should have factory ones.

Whenever I change the file though, git seems to force me to commit it to the repo.

This doesn't happen to other files, like `dev.exc` which is properly untracked.

I tried changing my ignored `.exc` file lines to this:

```
*.exc
!version.exc
test
```

(original:

```
dev.exc
save.exc
test
data/pinned.exc
```

)

But it still wants to track just *this one file* no matter what. What should I do?

Comment: I guess, this issue is more likely a duplicate of [Untrack files from git temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git-temporarily)

Comment: @wigi This didn't work with GitHub Desktop. I executed `git update-index --assume-unchanged data/pinned.exc`, but GHD still wants to update the file