# Is there a way to untrack files from git?

Tags: git

it seems like a similar question with [Untrack files from git temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git-temporarily)
but I can't find a good-working answer for me.

I'm running a python-django server and have trouble on `git merge`.

At the beginning of the project, a developer had committed all the *.pyc files on git, and these commits are used on the server as production code.

Now I have removed all the *.pyc files from the repository and make the proper .gitignore file.

But the problem occurs here.

Everything goes well till commit, but if I tried to merge it with production code, it emits an error.

> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Of course, the troubled files are the *.pyc files.

I assume it's because the *.pyc files are already tracked in some commits, and when trying to merge, git judge that the local *.pyc files will be removed by the commits which have 'delete: *.pyc' internally.

---

Describe it as an example :

Let's say I'm on branch A and want to merge branch B to branch A.
The top commit of branch B has no *.pyc file. And the top commit of branch A has *pyc files on the working tree, but they're already removed from index(stage) by `git rm --cached`.
When I try `git merge B` on branch A the error `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:` occurs.

Is there any feature to resolve it in git?

---

P.S.: I'm new in StackOverflow and not fluent in English.
If I made any mistake on this question or some phrases are hard to understand, please comment on me. Thank you.

---

Add git-status:

I can't upload the output with real file names, but it seems like below.
Just the file names differ.

```
  Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   files.pyc
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6964322/9523118 Check this link it might help

Comment: I've already viewed it. git update-index and git add -u both don't work in my case. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You need to commit the deletions made by `git rm --cached` before merging the other branch. From your question it seems that you missed this step.

Comment: Sorry I just didn't write that on question. I did commit and done succesfully.  But when merge, it occurs error. It seems to be caused by the tracking history of *.pyc files.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the output of `git status` just before you issue the command that results in the error?

Comment: According to the output of `git status`, all you needed to do was `git add *.pyc` or `git restore *.pyc`, then `git commit`, and only then `git merge`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* [resort to using filter-branch, as in Naeem Khoshnevis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67336211/1256452).  If you need to do a lot of work with the "bad" commits that contain the `*.pyc` files, this might even be the way to go.  The downside of doing this kind of work is that the product of `filter-branch` is usually a new, incompatible repository, that requires everyone who has a clone of the original repository, to throw out their clones, and painstakingly copy any work they had done on the original clone, over to the new clone.<sup>1</sup>  It may be better just to work around the problem:

- `*.pyc` files are simply byte-compiled Python code, made from the "real" Python source.
- They can therefore be *removed before and/or after merging*.
- So all you have to do is get ready for the merge step, then *make sure there are no `*.pyc` files* in your current commit and current working tree.  Then, do the merge.  If that introduces some `*.pyc` files, so be it: let that happen.  Then re-remove the files and commit this as a "repair the merge" step.

You're now done with the problematic merge.  The fact that the merge commit itself has incorrect `*.pyc` files *in* it is not really a problem *except* that the merge commit itself cannot be tested during bisection.  If you don't like that—it can be a problem later, because there's no obvious marker for this—you can consider making an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452) using `git merge -n` (then removing the `*.pyc` files before committing the merge), or using `git commit --amend` after the merge to replace the normal merge with the evil merge.

Note that no matter which of these various approaches you take, there is *some* pain.  That's unavoidable: someone made a mistake earlier, and everyone is now paying for it.  What you get to choose now is *which* painful process to go with, based on how painful you believe it will be.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some ways to automate some of this, especially in modern Git and/or using the new filter-repo system, but it's painful no matter what.

Comment: You don't need to painstakingly copy the work you've done in the old repo; fit allows you to cherry pick commits across unrelated histories, as long as the diffs "fit".

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to remove that file from your entire git history. In [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), you can read the "Removing a File from Every Commit" section. You need to use `git filter-branch` command.
Example from the book for removing password.txt from all commits.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD
```

Comment: For whom this answer will help. Detailed link : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_removing_file_every_commit