# Opposite of git add -p

Tags: git

Is there an opposite to `git add -p`? Sometimes I add a chunk by mistake and want to remove it from the index (which I do by `git reset; git add -p` and adding all the good chunks again). An `git remove-from-index -p` command would be helpful in this case.

Comment: +1 for formulating a question I had in the back of my head but never really asked myself until now

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the git-reset man page:

> This means that git reset -p is the opposite of git add -p
>
> ```
>                                   ^
>                                   |
>                         exact match of your post title
> ```

Answer (score -8):

Unfortunately, there is no direct opposite command. What you are looking for is to "unstage" a file (`git add` having staged the file for commit). Please see this answer for more details:

[Why are there 2 ways to unstage a file in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919121/why-are-there-2-ways-to-unstage-a-file-in-git)

Comment: erm, the accepted answer quotes reset manpage text contradicting this answer.