# Removing files from Git commit message

Tags: git, linux-kernel, kernel, patch

I've been working on kernel patches for the first time and I did 6 patches and added them to git. Now, whenever I commit all the files come up in the git commit message as follows: [image]

Now, I just want to send changes about one file at a time. I asked some people, they told I'd have to revert back the entire process and clone the staging repo again. Is there a way to remove the other files or at least revert back the changes to git?

I've used the following:

- git rm --cached
- git reset

Please tell if there's a way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `git reset` should be enough to unstage everything (if you haven't committed already), [as opposed to `rm --cached`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919257/6309) (which works only if the file wasn't tracked before).

From there, `git add <onefile>`, and the `git commit` will show you, in the "Changes to be committed" section, only that file.

Note that the other files will still be visible: they are displayed in *comment* section named "changes not staged for commit", and will *not* be part of the final commit message. You can ignore them: they are only listed to remind you of what remains to be added and committed.

Comment: Hi VonC! What I don't get is that the changes not staged for commit that are being shown here will also be sent once I try to send the patch if I have just one commit?

Comment: @timidgeek I have edited my answer to address your comment.