# Rollback commit of a single file git reset

Tags: git

I am using git on a terminal. I have few HTML files in a folder. I created a repository using git init.

I added index.html to the staging area using:

```
git add index.html
```

Now, I want to remove the index.html from the staging area. I tried git reset --HEAD index.html etc but nothing seems to be taking the file out of the staging area.

I want to simply remove the index.html file from the staging area.

Here is the output after running git reset HEAD. As you can see index.html is missing.

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    landscape.css
    max-640px.css
    min-640px.css
    portrait.css
    result.html
    styles.css
```

Here is git log output:

```
$ git log
commit d70e697ed08fbe6709ba3f13d202bade793e7b1a
Author: johnson 
Date:   Tue May 30 19:36:12 2017 -0500
```

Comment: `git reset HEAD index.html` should definitely work. Can you show the output of `git status`, please?

Comment: If you just created the repository, you can also just do `rm -rf .git; git init` to reinitialize the repository and start from scratch, although this should not be needed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'remove from the staging area'? `git reset` will definitely unstage the file, but it will not remove it from the working directory.

Comment: I want to remove it from the staging area. So, when I go git status then it should come as untracked files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there 2 ways to unstage a file in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919121/why-are-there-2-ways-to-unstage-a-file-in-git)

Comment: Although you seem to be missing some details.  If all you did was `git init` and `git add`, then your `git log` output should not contain any commits.

Comment: I added index.html file using git add index.html and then I also committed it. I guess the question is how to remove the file from the committed area.

Comment: Is the commit still local, or did you push it?

Comment: You just want `git reset HEAD^`

Comment: git reset HEAD^
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: I had to use a UI tool to un commit my changes. Now it shows up again in the staging area.

Comment: If the repository has been shared, then the only safe way to "uncommit" a file is `git revert HEAD`. This will create a new commit that will undo the previous commit. This will leave the file in your history. If you want to get it out of your history, use `filter-branch` (or BFG Repo Cleaner, for convenience), but note that whoever you shared the repo with might have issues.

Comment: Thanks looks like revert did the trick. IT is so much easier using a GUI tool :)

Comment: After revert for some reason it says deleted: index.html

Answer (score 1):

Before I start here, let's mention that the *very first* commit is special.  The reason is that until you make the *first* commit, there is no *current commit*.  For Git's own internal purposes, Git sometimes pretends that the current commit *does* exist anyway, and that it's truly empty: that it has no files at all.  ([In fact, there's a special semi-secret Git thing in every repository, for just such purposes.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452))

The staging area<sup>1</sup> sits *between* the *current* commit (HEAD) and the work-tree:

```
current commit:        staging area:         work-tree:
  file1                  file1                 file1
  file2                  file2                 file2
   ...                    ...                   ...
  fileN                  fileN                 fileN
```

The staging area (always) holds *all* the files that will go into the *next* commit.  If you have a current commit—which you do/did; you show it above—the staging area starts out full of *all the files that are in that commit*.  (So does the work tree: as you can see, there are *three* copies of every file!  Usually two of them—the current commit and staging area copies—are secretly compressed and/or secretly shared though.  Git can do this *because* those two copies are under Git's control.  It's only the work-tree copy that has the normal form of any file on your computer; Git can't keep these in fancy, compressed, de-duplicated form.)

In other words, as long as you have a *current* (`HEAD` or `@`) commit, the staging area is pretty much guaranteed to be loaded with lots of files.  It's just that the files stored there are *the same* as the ones stored in the current commit!  So `git status`, which compares `HEAD`-vs-stage, says nothing about them.

(Note: `git status` then *also* compares the staging area to the work-tree.  We'll see an example below, where `git status --short` prints *two* question marks to indicate an untracked file.  That's because the file will be in the work-tree, but not in *either* the current commit *or* the staging area.)

When you run `git reset --mixed commit path` (and `--mixed` is the default),<sup>2</sup> this tells Git: *please make the staged copy of* `path` *match the* `commit` *copy.*  Since this was `git reset HEAD index.html`, this means: if the file *isn't* in the `HEAD` commit, remove it from the staging area; if it *is* in the `HEAD` commit, copy it from the `HEAD` commit, back to the staging area.

Since `index.html` *is* in the `HEAD` commit, you're stuck with it being in *that* commit *forever*.  But you're not stuck with it in the staging area: you can, instead, use `git rm index.html` to remove it.  Of course, `git rm index.html` removes it from your work-tree as well!  Fortunately there's an option to tell `git rm`: *remove this from the staging area, but don't touch the work-tree*.  This is spelled `--cached`:

```
git rm --cached index.html
```

Now the *staging area* has no copy of `index.html`:

```
current commit:        staging area:         work-tree:
  foo.css                foo.css               foo.css
  index.html              ---                  index.html
  README                 README                README
```

This isn't what you did—using `git revert` makes a *new* commit that undoes a previous commit—but there's still an important point here, that would apply if you *had* done this.  The `git status` command compares the `HEAD` commit to the staging area.  The file `index.html` *is* (or would have been, before the revert) in the `HEAD` commit.  After `git rm --cached`, it is *not* in the staging area.  So the file becomes `deleted`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Just because it's Git, the *staging area* has two more names: it's also called the *cache* and, most commonly, the *index*.  Of course the name *index* is confusingly similar to `index.html`. :-)  So for the rest of this answer I am trying to stick with the phrase *staging area*.

<sup>2</sup>The reason this is `--mixed` is that there's a lower degree of `git reset`, `--soft`, that does not touch the staging area.  There's also a higher degree, `--hard`, that writes on both staging area *and* work-tree.

---

#### When you reverted, you made a new commit

If you use `git revert` to "undo" a commit, that just makes a new commit that does the opposite of the reverted commit.  The commit you reverted was the *first commit ever*, and the first commit, by definition, consists of *adding all the files* that are in that commit.  So reverting the first commit means: *remove all the files*.

Git's commits don't actually store *changes*, but rather *snapshots*.  Now that you have two commits, the `HEAD` (or current) commit is the *second* commit, which—compared to the *first* commit—removes all the files:

```
$ mkdir tt
$ cd tt
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo test revert of first commit > README
$ echo la la la > file
$ git add README file
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 2cff9aa] initial
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README
 create mode 100644 file
```

So far, so good: we have an initial commit, which (compared to the nothingness that precedes the initial commit) adds all the files.

```
$ git revert HEAD
[editor session, snipped]
[master 92f4eea] Revert "initial"
 2 files changed, 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 README
 delete mode 100644 file
```

The revert undoes the effect of the initial commit, so it *removes* all the files.  Git compares "previous commit" to "current commit" and sees that `README` and `file` are deleted.

```
$ ls
$
```

The work-tree is now *empty*.  All the files are gone!  This is because we've *reverted* them.

Don't worry though!  All the files are still there, too!  They are in that first commit.  We just have to get them back.  Let's do that now:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 92f4eea (HEAD -> master) Revert "initial"
* 2cff9aa initial
```

(Only the `--oneline` option does much here, but the rest are often a good idea.  I actually have this as a Git alias.  Remember this as: *when using `git log`, get help from A DOG: All Decorate Oneline Graph*.)

We need all the files back from the first commit (`2cff9aa`), so:

```
$ git checkout 2cff9aa -- .
$ ls
README  file
```

There's one fly in the ointment: *both* files are now *in the staging area*, and will hence go into the *next* commit:

```
$ git status
git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   README
    new file:   file
```

(This happens because `git checkout` *copies* the files from the specified commit, *to* the staging area, before finally copying them *from* the staging area *to* the work-tree.)

We want to get rid of one of them (`file`, in this case).  *Now* we can use *either* `git rm --cached` *or* `git reset HEAD file`.  The *current* commit, named `HEAD` or `@` or `92f4eea`, does *not* have the file `file` in it.  In fact, the current commit has *no files* in it!  It's a truly empty commit: checking it out makes your work-tree empty.

Let's reset (or `rm --cached`) now:

```
$ git reset file
$ git status --short
A  README
?? file
$ ls
README  file
```

The `A` status means "added", and the two question marks mean the file `file` is untracked (we'd see this spelled out explicitly in the longer default `git status` output).  So now we can commit:

```
$ git commit -m 'this should have been the first commit'
[master 0945e1d] this should have been the first commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git log --oneline
0945e1d (HEAD -> master) this should have been the first commit
92f4eea Revert "initial"
2cff9aa initial
```

There's a bit of a problem here now, perhaps best shown by illustration.  Note that we have our file `file` safely in the work-tree right now.  Let's check out the initial commit again, to see what was in it:

```
$ git checkout 2cff9aa
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    file
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Suppose we do manage to get that commit checked out, e.g., using `--force`:

```
$ git checkout --force 2cff9aa
Note: checking out '2cff9aa'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 2cff9aa... initial
$ ls
README  file
```

Now let's go back to the tip commit of `master`, getting back on branch `master` and out of this "detached HEAD" mode.

```
$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 2cff9aa... initial
Switched to branch 'master'
$ ls
README
```

Wait, where did our file named `file` go?

This is the trap we have created: there is a commit, `2cff9aa`, that has the file committed in it.  If we ever, somehow, manage to make that the *current* commit, we'll have that version of `file` in the staging area and work-tree too.  Then, when we move off that commit—say, back to `master`—Git will *remove* the file, both from the staging area *and* from the work-tree!

There is no way around this.  If the file *is* in a commit, it *will* go into the staging area (and work-tree) when you check it out.  It will then get *removed* (from those two same places) when you move off that commit to a commit that *doesn't* have the file.

Git will, as we saw above, warn you when you're about to move *to* that commit.  This gives you a chance to save your data.  You need to know that you must do that (save your data), or avoid checking out that particular commit.

The only other option is to rewrite your repository to get rid of that commit entirely.  In most cases—most repositories, with a lot of history in them, and perhaps many clones and so on—this isn't worth it.  In a *new* repository with only one commit, it might be worth it!