# Git ignore file change but only once?

Tags: git, git-track

Does Git have some kind of "ignore once" function?

I want git to ignore a change to a file only this time, is it possible?

I have a tracked file with variables , I want to change:

```
Debug: 'true'
```

too be 'false',

- I don't want the file to show up when staging files, so I can do a "stage all".
- I also don't want to add the file to .gitignore, because the file contains other variables that changes & should be tracked.
- I don't want to push the Debug: 'false', because that would just make other people have the opposite problem with wanting to have the Debug: 'true' without tracking.

Is this possible?

I'm aware of:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

But if I understand it correctly it will continue to not track the changes untill I use the --no-assume-unchanged flag to start tracking.

Can I first use --assume-unchanged then do the change & then use --no-assume-unchanged to bypass the tracking?

Comment: Why don't you stage all, then just [unstage that single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919121/why-are-there-2-ways-to-unstage-a-file-in-git) before you commit?

Comment: Because I make like 10 commits each day & don't want to unstage the file all the time.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that - once you `--no-assume-unchanged`, Git will detect your change and try to commit it, unless you are consciously avoiding it, never using `commit --auto`, and `add --patch` whenever you have changes in your config file that you do want to commit. In other words, you can only automatically ignore a file, you can't ignore a specific change in the file.

You *could* do the following sequence:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
git add --patch <file>
# pick and choose what you want for yourself only
git commit
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

each time you change something, but... what if someone forgets?

The typical way to solve this issue is to have an *uncommitted* config file (added to `.gitignore`), accompanied by a committed *example* of the config file (usually named `*.sample`, `*.example`, `*.skeleton` or similar). This way, changes are never propagated to your collaborators. When you make a change in the structure of the config file, make sure to also change the example, so other people can follow suit. Each collaborator would be expected to copy the example to create the real config file, which they can then customise for their environment.