# How to exclude .gitignore rules only once?

Tags: laravel, gitignore

Make once init of my laravel 8 app on server(ubuntu 20) I need to upload some images under storage, which is excluded
from git by .gitignore rules.

I do not like to remove .gitignore at all, but if there is a way to exclude these rules only once ?

Seems there is some force option, but how can I use it running command locally :

```
git push -u origin master
```

and on server :

```
git pull origin master
```

?

My root .gitignore:

```
# These are some examples of commonly ignored file patterns.
# You should customize this list as applicable to your project.
# Learn more about .gitignore:
#     https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore

# Node artifact files
node_modules/
dist/

# Compiled Java class files
*.class

# Compiled Python bytecode
*.py[cod]

# Log files
*.log

# Package files
*.jar

# Maven
target/
dist/

# JetBrains IDE
.idea/

# Unit test reports
TEST*.xml

# Generated by MacOS
.DS_Store

# Generated by Windows
Thumbs.db

# Applications
*.app
*.exe
*.war

# Large media files
*.mp4
*.tiff
*.avi
*.flv
*.mov
*.wmv


/public/js/laravel.app.js
/public/js/oneui.app.js
/public/js/tables_datatables.js
/public/css/oneui.css

composer.lock

package-lock.json

.env
vendor/
route_list.txt
```

Which is correct syntax ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your .gitignore file?

Comment: Plase check my root .gitignore. Do you to see some other .gitignore ?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you have some more .gitignore files ?

Comment: Maybe in subdirectories of the project there are. But now I have default rules that files under /storage are not pushed/pulled by git. I need to ignore these rules only once

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275676/git-ignore-file-change-but-only-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding  -f  key like:

```
git add -f storage/app/public/Photos/1/img-13.jpg
```

works in my case