# Initializing Git with a Mac

Tags: git

I am trying to learn Git. I have a Macbook and my instructor is on Windows. I installed Git using Homebrew. When I went to do a test run and create a simple folder on the desktop, with a file in it, to practice initializing Git on it...it worked...except, my MAC ALSO pulled two files which are typically hidden, a .localized file and a .DS_Store file and included them in my VS Code to be tracked. Now I can't figure out how to "untrack" them, and I tried
git rm --cached .localized (which as best as I could tell was the name of the file)
But this did not work.
How do I make sure I am only initializing the files I want?

Thank you sooo much, I do not usually work on the back end and want to learn for GitHub.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there two ways to unstage a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919121/why-are-there-two-ways-to-unstage-a-file-in-git)

Comment: Reading this a bit it sounds like I chose the right command, git rm --cached but it did not work with these files unless I have the file names wrong but I typed them as they appeared under git status

Comment: What does your `git status` says?

Comment: Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
 .DS_Store
 .localized

Comment: On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
 .DS_Store
 .localized

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: Well it says these files are _not_ tracked. Then nothing to do except maybe adding them to `.gitignore` to not be bothered with them in the future.

Comment: I am worried because they may become tracked once I do git add with the other files I DO want to practice tracking on, they just appeared out of nowhere... so if i type .gitignore and the file name?

Comment: It says .gitignore is not a command I also tried git ignore

Comment: You have to create a file named `.gitignore` and add the names of the files to ignore in it. There is probably an answer on SO explaining how.

Comment: Documentation on .gitignore file: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore. Repository of recommended .gitignore files: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a file in your repository with the name `.gitignore` which has the following contents:

```
.DS_Store
.localized
```

The content of this file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. You can find more details in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore/en). This will prevent you from unintentionally staging/committing them in the future.

GitHub has a collection of useful templates [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore). There are some generators online that can be used to create more comprehensive `.gitignore` files to handle the most common OS, IDEs, frameworks etc. One example is [gitignore.io](https://gitignore.io)