# How to stop tracking a folder with git (Visual Studio)

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've choose wrong folder to track with git (that's the 'HtmlFiles' - the root folder, I want to track only 'Google Translate Dark Theme' - the subfolder. How to stop tracking folder in visual studio?
[here's screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj9fB.png)

I've tried some commands in visual studio terminal, but probably that's not the one terminal that I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there are two ways to unstage a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919121/why-there-are-two-ways-to-unstage-a-file-in-git)

Comment: remove the `.git` folder, but VSC probably expects the `.git` folder in the workspace root folder

Comment: is this about VS Code? or is it about Visual Studio? They are not the same/