# Unstage file in a git repo where there are no commits

Tags: git

Is there a way to unstage a file in a git repository with no commits?

If you try doing a `git add .` on a newly created git repo with no commits, and then try to do a `git reset` you get the following from git:

Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.

Is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stupidly, its right in the `git status` output:

`git rm --cached -r .`

Comment: cheers, although if I had read the output of `git status` or found the second answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add) I would have saved time :)