# Checkout multiple files which have been moved in the working tree

Tags: git

I've moved files from `Project` to `Project/src`. Git is under the impression that I've deleted the files from `Project` and created new files in `Project/src`.

In addition, I have multiple other changes in the working tree, which I wish to commit. My `git status`:

```
 $ git  status
# On branch feature/cmake
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .gitignore
#   new file:   CMakeLists.txt
#   deleted:    Wasa.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
#   deleted:    Wasa/Wasa.1
#   renamed:    Wasa/main.cpp -> main.cpp
#   new file:   src/CMakeLists.txt  
#  Lots of new files listed here
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   CMakeLists.txt
#   deleted:    IODevice.h
#  Lots of deleted files listed here.
```

I'd like to unstage the source files - `*.{cpp,h}`. I know how to unstage (the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit), for example, is helpful). What I'd like to *avoid* doing is typing lots of `git checkout <filename>`.

I don't want to checkout `HEAD`, because some of the changes in the working tree I'd like to keep. I've tried doing `git checkout *.{cpp,h}`, which gives the following:

```
$ git checkout *.{cpp,h}
zsh: no matches found: *.cpp
```

Because the files don't currently exist in the working tree, I can't check them out because `*.{cpp,h}` doesn't match any files.

The files are all in `Project/src`; there is probably a regex or something I could run with the output of `ls src` piped into the `git checkout` command, but I'd like to know if git can do this for me by itself. Is there a way I can do this in git?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Escape the `*`:

```
$ git checkout \*.{cpp,h}
```

Comment: If the files exist in the directory, git (or maybe the shell, I'm not sure which) accepts the `*.{cpp,h}` and expands it to all matching files. My issue is that I don't *have* matching files; they've moved to `src/*.{cpp,h}` and I'm trying to find a lazy way to checkout the files without typing `git checkout <filename1>`, `git checkout <filename2>` etc.

Comment: If you escape the star, it won't match in the shell. Just try it :-)

Comment: Heh. My bad; completely mis-read what you'd written. That works - thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but the complete command would help. Thanks

Comment: `$ git checkout \*.{cpp,h}` will check out any files matching the shell glob pattern `*.{cpp,h}` *in the repository*. Without the backslash, it would have matched against (and expanded to) files *in the current directory*.

Answer (score 2):

For checking out multiple files. I just implemented the wildcards, and it worked well for me. 
For specific files, we'd probably require a different trick.

I used:

`git checkout -- *.*`

in my Git Bash. and all the modified files in my workspace were replaced with the ones in the repo.

I hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: The problem with this is exactly what is pointed out in the accepted answer, that `*` is expanded by the shell (bash, zsh...) to all matching files, which might be none, if you have moved/removed them. While `\*` in this context is expanded by `git` to the files that are tracked by git i.e. `git add` has been applied to them. Even if the files are moved/removed `git checkout \*` will expand to those filenames until you commit moving/removing them. In fact, to commit the removal of `file.end` you have to do `git commit file.end` and yet that file isn't even there (but to git it is).

Comment: That's very true. 
Thanks Jonatan. Sorry about the noobness