# Undo git add --all

Tags: git, git-add

I made a mistake and called `git add -all`, now all files are added. I did not make a `commit` and `push`. How can I *undo* my action?

Comment: did you try `git reset HEAD` ?

Comment: this is not a duplicate since clearly it is stated this is undo git add -all. There are many resources for undoing git add but for -all there are very few.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It has already been answered several times:

> You can use `git reset`. This will 'unstage' all the files you've
>   added after your last commit.
>
> If you want to unstage only some files, use `git reset -- <file 1>
>   <file 2> <file n>`.
>
> Also it's possible to unstage some of the changes in files by using
>   `git reset -p`.

See

- [How to undo 'git add' before commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit)
- [How can you undo the last git add?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132272/how-can-you-undo-the-last-git-add)

Comment: If it was already answered several times, the correct course of action would be to vote to mark as duplicate, and not answer the question.

Comment: @SecondRikudo That's what I did, look at my comment at the top. The reason I posted is to provide more than one answer link.

Comment: Emphasizing the **and not answer the question** part. The idea is that if someone searches Google for this problem, they'd find the canonical with the best answer, and not one of the many duplicates asked. By answering these questions you're giving them more visibility.

Comment: I did this reset and it said it unstaged them but they're still in the index because if I a git status it shows them marked as modified still.  How do I COMPLETELY get rid of changes bot added and committed locally?

Comment: I searched and couldn't find the many answers

Answer (score 14):

To reset specific files you can use: `git reset -- <file_a> <file_b>` or to reset all your changes you can use `git reset`.