# time of last git-add

Tags: git, git-add

### **Note**, please be kindly to read my question first, befroe mark it as duplicate of [how-can-you-undo-the-last-git-add](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12132272/6521116).

Is there a git native way to get  when the last `git add .` executed?

I recent do some coding in my ios project, and execute `git add .` without committing.
Today I also do some coding in the project, and encountered a bug. I use `git diff` to check today's work, and not find any changes may lead to the bug.

I've test the ios app on my device last saturday. So I want to know when the last `git add .` was executed. If it was executed before last saturday, I can locate the bug in today's code.

Comment: Check the timestamp of `.git/index` if you haven't run any other commands that touch the file. Besides, `history` helps if you have configured something like https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/

Comment: The above comment is the only way I can think of. However, you should make small and frequent commits so that you can get a fine grained history to figure out such bugs.

Comment: Use git reflog command to see the command history that will help you to know what command executed last.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I use `git reflog -all`, it not show command like `git add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `.git/index` or check the bash history. Refer to ElpieKay's comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

I suggest you commit code as soon as you can, and later you can easily merge multiple commit to a single commit using `git-rebase`

Comment: your solution won't give his difference of buggy code that OP has done. Please see what exactly he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Convert your `added` / `staged` Stated files (which you have done via `git add .`) to `modified` state using below command first :

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

And then use :

```
git diff
```

So that you can now see the Code difference.

**For Reference :**

> When you start an empty repository and add a file, it will be in the
>   `untracked` state,
>
> When you use `git add`, Those files are now in `staged` state and
>   ready to be committed inside the repository
>
> To UNDO `git add`, just use `git reset HEAD~1`, so `staged` state
>   files can be converted to `untracked` state.

Answer (score 0):

A best effort way: to examine creation date of blob file.

This is definitely not the most simple way, but it may work even if we `git add` more than once.

When we `git add` a file, git *may* create a blob file in `.git/objects`:

(It may also reuse existing blobs without create new file)

```
# add a new file to index
$ echo gimme-a-new-blob > a
$ git add a

# list blob objects in stash
$ git ls-files --stage
...
100644 facd29e7e5ab3a8764cd7702daefc4f2b6515edd 0       a
...

# check the blob file, filenamed is based on sha1 of that blob
$ ls -l .git/objects/fa/cd*
19 Jun  1 21:14 .git/objects/fa/cd29e7e5ab3a8764cd7702daefc4f2b6515edd
```

If we check all the blobs for files in index, the latest creation date may be what you want.