# Cannot remove file from "staging phase" in git

Tags: git

I am very new to git. What I did so far in it was this:

```
    $git init
    $git add "folder/*.php"
```

Now, I cannot remove the php files from the staging phase...
what it returns:

```
    $git rm --cached "folder/*.php"
    fatal: 'folder/*.php' is outside repository
```

What do I do now?
my git version is 1.7.1

Comment: I tried the same sequence of commands and it worked for me...

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit

Comment: If there are no commits yet, you are probably faster if you just remove the Git directory (`rm -r .git`) and start anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error occurs because those files are not added to the repository yet. When you do a `git add`, what git does is just to add files into a "list" that will be commit to the repository.

In order to "make these files part of the repository", what you can do is:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Then:

```
git rm folder/*.php
```

Now since you remove files, you need to commit again to update git history about the remove.