# how to undo git add before commit

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undo git add before commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit)

When i was working on my project I accidently added files using the following command

```
git add file
```

I haven't yet run

```
git commit.
```

How can I undo or remove these newly added files from the commit?

Please help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`git reset` is a literally "undo" of `git add` - it removes the changes from staged area.

Comment: and as @Nic said in a later answer -- `git reset HEAD <somefile>` to unstage a specific file