# Git to show complete staged file

Tags: git

So I have the following situation:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   ../push-test.xml
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   ../push-test.xml
```

I would like to print contents of staged push-test.xml. How to achieve it?

Comment: Have you changed `push-test.xml` since staging it? If not, `cat ../push-test.xml` will do it.

Comment: @peachykeen That's already answered in the question: `../push-test.xml` is also mentioned in "Changes not staged for commit"

Comment: @peachykeen Yes, I have changed push-test.xml since staging as `git status` shows promptly

Comment: How did you end up with this?I think you did `git stash pop` and the stash had a version of the same file that was already staged for commit.

Comment: @Cratylus This is a normal state for git, it's what happens when you modify a file, do `git add`, don't commit, and make further modifications to the file.

Comment: @hvd Yeah, you are right - it is a duplicate. I googled with wrong words

Comment: @hvd:Ah, right! I am new to git. I think the OP needs this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/undo-git-add-before-commit?rq=1

Comment: Voted to close as the duplicate..